# palindrome detection palindrome

Tags: popularity-contest, string

Write a function with a single string parameter and a boolean return value. The function should return true iff the string is a palindrome character-wise.

Alternatively, write a program that reads a string from standard input and writes 1/0 to standard output depending on whether the string is palindrome or not.

**The code itself should be a palindrome**. The structure of the code visually documents what the code is about.

Since this is all about beauty of code, the code with the most votes wins.

Comment: @KendallFrey you are right... I mistakenly searched for palyndrome with y.

Comment: Would adding another constraint make the question unique enough?  I notice that most of the solutions to the other problem use comments.  I think it would be interesting to see a challenge where comments are forbidden.

Comment: @Josh good point, but I see the duplicate question already has some very nice answers without using comments.

Comment: Maybe mirroring, without using comments? - `(` -> `)`, `[` -> `]`, etc.