# I'm a palindrome. Are you?

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem, restricted-source, palindrome

> There have been a couple of [previous](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1798/62131) [attempts](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/19594/62131) to ask this question, but neither conforms to modern standards on this site. Per [discussion on Meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/11600/62131), I'm reposting it in a way that allows for fair competition under our modern rulesets.

### Background

A [palindrome](/questions/tagged/palindrome) is a string that "reads the same forwards and backwards", i.e. the reverse of the string is the same as the string itself. We're not talking about "convenient palindromes" here, but a strict character-by-character reversal; for example, `()()` is not a palindrome, but `())(` is.

### The task

Write a program or function that takes a string *S* (or the appropriate equivalent in your language) as input, and has one output *Q* (of a type of your choice). You can use [any reasonable means](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods?noredirect=1&lq=1) to take the input and provide the output.

- When the input *S* is a palindrome, the output *Q* should have a value *A* (that is the same for any palindromic *S*).
- When the input *S* is not a palindrome, the output *Q* should have a value *B* (that is the same for any non-palindromic *S*).
- *A* and *B* must be distinct from each other.

Or in other words: map all palindromes to one value, and all non-palindromes to another.

Additionally, the program or function you write must be a palindrome itself (i.e. its source code must be palindromic), making this a [restricted-source](/questions/tagged/restricted-source) challenge.

### Clarifications

- Although `true` and `false` are obvious choices for *A* and *B*, you can use any two distinct values for your "is a palindrome" and "isn't a palindrome" outputs, which need not be booleans.
- We're defining string reversal at the *character* level here; `éé` is palindromic regardless of whether the program is encoded in UTF-8 or Latin-1, even though it's not a palindromic sequence of octets after UTF-8 encoding.
- However, even if your program contains non-ASCII characters, it only needs to work for ASCII input. Specifically, the input *S* will only contain printable ASCII characters (including space, but not including newline). Among other things, this means that if you treat the input as a sequence of bytes rather than a sequence of characters, your program will still likely comply with the specification (unless your language's I/O encoding is *very* weird). As such, the definition of a palindrome in the previous bullet only really matters when checking that the program has a correct form.
- Hiding half the program in a comment or string literal, while being uncreative, is legal; you're being scored on length, not creativity, so feel free to use "boring" methods to ensure your program is a palindrome. Of course, because you're being scored on length, parts of your program that don't do anything are going to worsen your score, so being able to use both halves of your program is likely going to be helpful if you can manage it.
- Because the victory criterion is measured in bytes, you'll need to specify the encoding in which your program is written to be able to score it (although in many cases it will be obvious which encoding you're using).

### Victory criterion

Even though the program needs to be a palindrome at the character level, we're using bytes to see who wins. Specifically, the shorter your program is, measured in bytes, the better; this is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge. In order to allow submissions (especially submissions in the same language) to be compared, place a byte count for your program in the header of your submission (plus a character count, if it differs from the number of bytes).

Comment: Would someone please explain why would ()() not be a palindrome??

Comment: @EmilioMBumachar Try replacing `(` with `a` and `)` with `b`.  Is `abab` a palindrome? No, it would have to be `abba`. Then `()()` isn't a palindrome either; it would have to be `())(`.

Comment: Those solutions entirely using comments to make the program palindromic looks like a loophole to me :(

Comment: @kennytm The OP himself allows it.

Comment: Can I give no output if S is not a palindrome and print 1 if it is?

Comment: @kennytm Disallowing them would be worse, because there's no satisfactory way to do that objectively in a language-agnostic way. (What's a comment? What about putting the unused half in a string literal that is discarded? What about 2D languages where you can have perfectly executable code that is simply never reached?)

Comment: I think another interesting result of this could be the longest program in which every bit of code is executed. I.E., there are no comments or sections of code that are never reached just to make it a palindrome.

Comment: @EngineerToast: We've had a few challenges along those lines. The solution nearly always ends up to be putting most of the program in a string literal, and then using some sort of checksum to ensure that it actually has an effect on the program, which probably isn't what you were expecting.

Comment: I had to join this stack just to leave a comment and up-vote here.  It boggles the mind how you guys come up with these challenges that look complex yet get solved in 3 bytes in a bunch languages, even regular ones.

Comment: `()() is not a palindrome, but ())( is.`
[Congratulations, you made it onto reddit!](https://www.reddit.com/r/Showerthoughts/comments/5vkrg5/)

Comment: This one popped back up to the top of the stack and I have to ask, is `éé` a palindrome? (Fair warning, it is not strictly equal to `éé`). Reversed by unicode character endpoints, it would be `́ée`.

Comment: Can *S* be the empty string ""?

Answer (score 139):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) (2), 3 bytes in Brachylog's codepage

```
I↔I
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@@/5qG2K5///SkWJyanJiUVKAA)

This is a full program that takes input via standard input (using Brachylog's syntax for constants, i.e. strings are enclosed in double quotes), and outputs via standard output. The outputs are `true.` for a palindromic input, and `false.` for a non-palindromic input.

Not only is this program palindromic, it also has left/right (and probably in some fonts up/down) mirror symmetry.

### Explanation

In Brachylog, capital letters mark points in the program which have identical values; this is used almost like an electrical circuit to carry information from one part of the program to another. One consequence of this is that if you enclose a command between an identical pair of capital letters, you're effectively asserting that the command's input and output are the same. Brachylog implicitly takes input, so in this case we're also asserting that the input to the command is the same as the input to the program. In this program, we're using the command `↔`, which reverses things (in this case, strings); so the program effectively asserts that the input is the same forwards and backwards.

A full program (as opposed to a function) in Brachylog returns a boolean, `false.` if there's no way to make all the assertions in the program correct at once, or `true.` if the assertions in the program are all compatible with each other. We only have one assertion here – that reversing the input does not change it – so the program acts as a palindrome checker.

Comment: And 180 degree rotational symmetry, It's beautiful.

Comment: ... and symmetry along vertical and horizontal axes :-)

Comment: More like 5 bytes in UTF-8, isn't it?

Comment: @SteakOverflow Brachylog uses a [custom code-page](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog/wiki/Code-page), so those characters are not encoded in UTF-8

Comment: I joined this community just to up vote this program. Wow.

Comment: @ATaco The combination of left/right and up/down symmetries imply 180 degree rotational symmetry. ;)

Comment: This is the best program of all time!

Answer (score 57):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 3 bytes

```
_I_
```

Returns *True* or *False*.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pyth#@x/vGf//v3piUnJSojoA)

#### How it works

```
  _  Reverse the input.
_I   Invariant-reverse; test if the reversed input is equal to its reverse.
```

Comment: Why do you need the final `_`?

Comment: @busukxuan From the question, "Additionally, the program or function you write must be a palindrome itself"

Comment: Why so many upvotes...This answer doesn't seem that hard to come up with...?

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code The vast majority of answers to this challenge weren't difficult to come up with...

Comment: I guess so. Still it seems kind of unfair. On some questions, one must put a lot of hard work to answer, and others are much easier. Still the payout is the same. Btw I've also upvoted :P

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code Only one of my answers with 100+ was actually challenging to write, yet there are answers I spent days on that only got a handful of upvotes. In the end, it all evens out...

Answer (score 50):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org), 39 bytes

```python
lambda s:s[::-1]==s#s==]1-::[s:s adbmal
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#JYzBCsQgEEPPu18xsAcV2kOvA/MlrgVLFQqtFkeEfr219ZDkEUI8/etuj2W1wMgacZwMEf@YyEwjom4t2HU57F59TJAdZ9gCaCEGIR@9prq/MV@O3TU3CrGUFiWU2EdKGPx@zrSFLJM7k3zu1AC@g6r1Bg)

Boring, but if there is shorter in Python it will be impressive.

Comment: Wow, thos `(`, `)` were some good (and confusing) inputs :)

Answer (score 35):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
ḂŒ
ŒḂ
```

Returns **1** or **0**. The first line is an unexecuted helper link, the second line calls the palindrome test.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9wR9PRSVxHJwHp////qycmJSclqgMA)

Comment: wow, recent addition.

Comment: Yep, only 18 hours old.

Comment: you didn't specify the encoding. I'm guessing UTF-8?

Comment: @BrianMinton No, this would be 11 bytes in UTF-8. Jelly uses [this code page](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page).

Comment: @Dennis, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 25):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
⁼ṚaṚ⁼
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@occ/DnbMSgRjI@n@4/VHTmv//o9XVddQ1QBhMaEJIMGVTmVqcWmkDZOXl29kBKbs8u3yIIk31WAA)

Equals reverse and reverse equals.

Or the more efficient yet less aesthetically pleasing:

```
⁼Ṛ
Ṛ⁼
```

or

```
Ṛ⁼
⁼Ṛ
```

Answer (score 24):

## Haskell, <s>87</s> <s>85</s> <s>44</s> 34 bytes

```
p=(==)<*>reverse--esrever>*<)==(=p
```

Explanation: `((->) a)` is an instance of Applicative (thanks @faubiguy), with `<*>` defined as

```
(<*>) f g x = f x (g x)
```

So by substituting in the arguments one can see why this works.

Comment: Can you explain the code?

Comment: @bli everything after the `--` is a comment.

Comment: @theonlygusti Haskell is sufficiently alien that that only half helps.

Comment: @Yakk It's some sort of combination of the `(==)`, `reverse`, and `id` functions (`id` is the identity function).

Comment: You can save 10 bytes by using `<*>` instead of `<$>` and removing the `<*>id`

Comment: Nice thinking! Applicative is still weird to me...

Comment: `f=reverse>>=(==)` works too for the same reasoning and the `Monad ((->) r)` instance which looks like `f >>= g = \x -> g (f x) x` and is essentially flipping the arguments of the combining function

Answer (score 23):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

Code:

```
ÂQÂ
```

Explanation:

```
Â     # Bifurcate (duplicate and reverse the duplicate) implicit input
 Q    # Check if equal
  Â   # Bifurcate the result
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@3@4KfBw0///RYnJqcmJRQA)

Comment: Why not just `ÂQ`

Comment: @NeilA. The code itself needs to be a palindrome as well.

Answer (score 23):

### Mathematica, 23 bytes

```
QemordnilaP;PalindromeQ
```

Not very interesting, but for the sake of completeness...

The above is a `CompoundExpression` which evaluates to `PalindromeQ`, a built-in that solves the challenge. `QemordnilaP` is simply an undefined identifier, which is ignored because of the `;`.

Answer (score 19):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 55 bytes

```php
<?=strrev($s=$argv[1])==$s;#;s$==)]s[TEG_$=s$(verrts=?<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt62uKSoKLVMQ6XYViWxKL0s2jBW09ZWpdha2bpYxdZWM7Y4OsTVPV7FtlhFoyy1qKik2Nbe5v///@X55QA)

Comment: Sneaky solution.

Answer (score 17):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 7 bytes

```
tPX=XPt
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@18SEGEbEVDy/7@6RlFicmpyYpGGOgA)

Returns [1; 1] for palindromic input and [0; 0] otherwise.

```
t       % duplicate the input
P       % reverse the second string
X=      % check the two strings are exactly equal (returns 0 or 1)
XP      % flip array (does nothing)
t       % duplicate the answer, giving either [1;1] or [0;0]
        % (implicit) convert to string and display
```

Answer (score 16):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

Now comment-free!

```
x:RVaQaVR:x
```

Takes input as a command-line argument; outputs `1` for palindrome, `0` for non-palindrome. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#@19hFRSWGJgYFmRV8f///9zElMTcTDAJAA)

The core of what we want to do is `RVaQa`: `reverse(a) string-equals a`. The code `x:RVaQa` calculates this result and assigns it to `x`. Then `VR:x` assigns the value of `x` to the variable `VR`. Since this assignment is the last statement in the program, its value is also autoprinted. Voila!

For a previous interesting version using some undefined behavior, see the revision history.

Answer (score 13):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 25 bytes/chars utf8

```perl6
{.flip eq$_}#}_$qe pilf.{
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#FcvBDcIgGAbQO1N8iSglqdz0YjoLIfQnktBCSzVpSAfqHJ3JM@q7v1cmvO/KPtiw4mJjT@hqUS74BJq43k6b5hMh@eBUqS7OCH6k3EgUBmSz4p8arqVyw9KI8y0L2UJAtFCJ5sC2euzHzsa4wCCZX@/nONBnjFdr7JO@)

Answer (score 10):

### R, <s>111</s> 103 bytes

```
all((s<-el(strsplit(scan(,"",,,"\n"),"")))==rev(s))#))s(ver==)))"",)"n\",,,"",(nacs(tilpsrts(le-<s((lla
```

Not the most original answer. `#` is the comment character in **R**

**Ungolfed:**

```
all((s<-el(strsplit(scan(,"",,,"\n"),"")))==rev(s))
#
))s(ver==)))"",)"n\",,,"",(nacs(tilpsrts(le-<s((lla
```

The character string from `scan` is converted into raw bytes thanks to the `charToRaw` function. These raw bytes are compared one-by-one to their counterparts from the `rev()` function, which reverses the order of its argument. The output of this part is a vector of `TRUE` and/or `FALSE`.
The `all` function then outputs `TRUE` if all those elements are `TRUE`

Here, `"\n"` in the `scan` function is necessary for inputs with more than one word.

#### Previous answer (byte-wise), **81 bytes**

```
function(s)all((s=charToRaw(s))==rev(s))#))s(ver==))s(waRoTr‌​ahc=s((lla)s(noitcnu‌​f
```

with *- 24 bytes* thanks to [@rturnbull](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59052/rturnbull).

Comment: You can save a good few bytes by doing the `charToRaw` conversion before assignment to `s`, and changing how you set the `sep` argument to `scan`: `all((s<-charToRaw(scan(,"",,,"\n")))==rev(s))#))s(ver==)))"n\",,,"",(nacs(waRoTrahc-<s((lla`

Comment: (Also, this approach doesn't work for e.g. input `éé` under a UTF-8 encoding, but I don't think that breaks the rules of the challenge.)

Comment: @rturnbull : thanks for the inputs ! I indeed tested `éé` with a `latin1` encoding.

Comment: Since the test must be done character-wise, I think the current programm breaks the rules.

Comment: I'm not so sure the previous version does break the rules. OP states: "Among other things, this means that if you treat the input as a sequence of bytes rather than a sequence of characters, your program will still likely comply with the specification (unless your language's I/O encoding is very weird)."

Comment: But if you insist on the new version, you can replace `s<-unlist(` with `s=el(` to save a few bytes.

Comment: A further improvement on the byte-comparison method: an anonymous function for **81 bytes** `function(s)all((s=charToRaw(s))==rev(s))#))s(ver==))s(waRoTrahc=s((lla)s(noitcnuf`

Comment: @rturnbull : It's the *"We're defining string reversal at the character level here; `éé` is palindromic regardless of whether the program is encoded in UTF-8 or Latin-1"* part that made me doubt. Nice function too !

Comment: @count : It does work as is, but since nothing is said about lower/uppercase, you could drop this part. `strsplit(x)[[1]]` can be replace by `el(strsplit(x))`. You end up with a 56 bytes `function(x)paste(rev(el(strsplit(x,""))),collapse="")==x` anonymous function. In the palindromic-ing process, you gain 57 bytes. Nice inputs though !

Comment: This isn't a palindrome, the parenthesis are wrong.

Comment: `utf8ToInt` is shorter than `strsplit`. It'll work for all ASCII: [try it online](https://tio.run/##rcy7CQAhEAXAXvaSt6C5gRZgbgMiGomCP7Z774q4dIIZ98ZaAbF6r2JC921hptigiJjZuZEPhPlhFpw8nPuUSKHFNLGa78GUtbUVoNb48/YC)

Answer (score 10):

### [GNU sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed), <s>64</s> 59 + 1(r flag) = 60 bytes UTF-8

Took me a while to come up with a sed answer that is not using a comment section to make the code a palindrome. Instead, I use the `c` command that would print the first half of the code in reverse order, only I make sure this instruction is not reached.

```sed
:;s:^(.)(.*)\1$:\2:;t;/../c1
d
1c/../;t;:2\:$1\)*.().(^:s;:
```

The script prints **`1`** if the input string is not a palindrome (think of it as giving an error). If the string is a palindrome, then **no output** is given (think of it as exiting successfully).

**Run examples:** or [**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#FcgxCsAgDAXQ3VM4CCaFRuL4cxURikqnLrX3t@32eHN0v98@LthEJWGSjYsGlAx7LImkpq47bT@/QS4IWngTYqGKaVhxncc1Xg)

```sh
me@LCARS:/PPCG$ sed -rf palindrome_source.sed <<< "level"
me@LCARS:/PPCG$ sed -rf palindrome_source.sed <<< "game"
1
```

**Explanation:**

```sed
:                              # start loop
s:^(.)(.*)\1$:\2:              # delete first and last char, if they are the same
t                              # repeat if 's' was successful
/../c1                         # if at least 2 chars are left, print 1. 'c' reads
                               #till EOL, so next command must be on a new line.
d                              # delete pattern space. This line must be a
                               #palindrome itself, and must end the script.
1c/../;t;:2\:$1\)*.().(^:s;:   # (skipped) print first half of code in reverse
                               #order. Everything after 'c' is treated as string.
```

Comment: TIO has support for sed now. `-r` doesn't work, but you can just wrap the whole thing in BASH. [Try it Online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#FcgxCsAgDAXQ3VM4FEyERuL4cxVxUTenWnp9226Pt0b35@XDhi1UEiaJXPRAybDbkkhq6rrT9vMb5IJDC0chFqpYhh32HM@YLw)

Comment: @Riley Nice usage of header and footer on TIO, thanks. The previous workaround was to move the code to the argument list with -e, but your way is much nicer. I was waiting for that to be fixed, but this way I don't need to.

Comment: Nice answer.  I think you can -2 changing `/../` to `/./`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcc7DoAgDADQnXMwtCSWwFiu0pDwcXARI5zfyvbePLsqp8kZCIEcSrAskdNKnnwLppvQtvY5Ctsg6AiQIPNMrFpqLd941jXuqcf7Aw "sed 4.2.2 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 9):

## [RProgN](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Reverse-Programmer-Notation), 11 bytes

```
~]S.E E.S]~
```

The first half of this does all the heavy lifting, and by a convenience of RProgN, the second half is a No-op.

```
~]S.E E.S]~
~           # Treat the word as a Zero Space Segment
 ]          # Duplicate the top of the stack
  S.        # Reverse the top of the stack
    E       # Compare if these values are equal
      E.S]~ # A no-op, because the ~ is at the end of the word, not the start.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/rprogn#@18XG6znquCqFxxb9////6LE5NTkxCIA)

Answer (score 9):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 19 bytes

```
/@.nzRoi\
\ioRzn.@/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#@6/voJdXFZSfGcMVk5kfVJWn56D//39RYnJqcmIRAA)

Prints `Jabberwocky` for palindromes and nothing for non-palindromes. Works for arbitrary UTF-8 input.

#### Explanation

Since this is a string processing task, Alice will have to operate in Ordinal mode to solve it. That in turn means that the instruction pointer has to move diagonally, and therefore we need at least two lines so that the IP can bounce up and down. The linefeed in such a program makes for a good position to place the middle character of the palindrome. That means the second line needs to be the reverse of the first. But since we're only executing every other character on each line, if we make sure that the line-length is odd, the reverse of the code will neatly fit into its own gaps. The only character that isn't used at all is the backslash, but since it was arbitrary I chose it to make the program look nice and symmetric.

So anyway, the actual relevant code is this:

```
/ . z o
 i R n @
```

Which is executed in a zigzag from left to right.

```
/   Reflect the IP southeast, enter Ordinal mode.
i   Read all input as a single string.
.   Duplicate the input.
R   Reverse the copy.
z   Pop the reverse Y and the original X. If X contains Y, drop everything
    up to its first occurrence. Since we know that X and Y are the same length,
    Y can only be contained in X if X=Y, which means that X is a palindrome.
    So this will result in an empty string for palindromes and in the non-empty
    input for non-palindromes.
n   Logical NOT. Replaces non-empty strings with "", and empty strings with
    "Jabberwocky", the "default" truthy string.
o   Output the result.
@   Terminate the program.
```

Answer (score 8):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 53 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
$
¶$`
O$^`\G.
»
D`
M$`^.+$
$+.^`$M
`D
»
.G\`^$O
`$¶
$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#Fcm7CQAhEATQfOqYTNgqBCOxAVnGz7VocpmN7XEvfUHcQ6HR1YvhvshCpdwSwWQuVij/YaXL2SDeA0aMufaz1xwf)

I'm pretty sure this isn't optimal yet (the `»` line seems particularly wasteful, and I have a 45-byte solution that is palindromic except for one character), but I guess it's a start.

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 34 bytes

```hs
f=(==)=<<reverse--esrever<<=)==(=f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@59mq2Frq2lrY1OUWpZaVJyqq5taDGba2ACFgZJp/3MTM/MUbBUy80pSixKTSxRUFIoz8sv10v4T1gsA) Call with `f "some string"`, returns `True` or `False`.

The `=<<` operator on functions works like `f=<<g = \s -> f (g s) s`, so the code is equivalent to `f s=s==reverse s`, which, as I just noticed, would result in the same byte count.

---

**Version without comment:** (49 bytes)

```hs
e x y=x/=y
p=e=<<reverse
esrever<<=e=p
y=/x=y x e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@5@qUKFQaVuhb1vJVWCbamtjU5RallpUnMqVWgxm2dgARQu4Km31K2wrgWpT/@cmZuYp2Cpk5pWkFiUmlyioKBRn5JfrFfwn2SgA)

Call with `p "some string"`. This outputs `False` if the given string **is** a palindrome, and `True` if it's **not** a palindrome.

**Explanation:**

I found this comment free palindrome by starting with the comment version and replacing the the comment with a new line:

```hs
p=(==)=<<reverse
esrever<<=)==(=p
```

The second line fails because the parenthesis do not match, so we need to get rid of them. If we had a function `e` which checks for equality, then

```hs
p=e=<<reverse
esrever<<=e=p
```

will both compile with the second line defining an infix-operator `<<=` which takes two arguments `esrever` and `e` and returns the function `p`.

To define `e` as the equality function one would normally write `e=(==)`, but `)==(=e` will again not compile. Instead we could explicitly take two arguments and pass them to `==`: `e x y=x==y`. Now the reversed code `y==x=y x e` compiles but redefines the `==` operator, which causes the definition `e x y=x==y` to fail. However if we switch to the inequality operator `/=`, the reversed definition becomes `y=/x=y x e` and defines a `=/` operator which does not interferes with the original `/=` operator.

Answer (score 6):

## [OIL](https://github.com/L3viathan/OIL), 178 bytes

Reads an input, explodes it, slowly adds its length (through incrementing and decrementing) to the address to know to the address after the string, jumps to a different part of code (in the middle), reverses the band direction, implodes the string again, and checks whether it's the same as the original string. TL;DR: It's a pain, as usual.

Outputs `40` if the string isn't a palindrome, `0` if it is.

```
5
0
12
0
40
1
40
2
1
40
34
10
2
3
22
16
9
2
8
35
6
11
6
37

3
4
4
27
26
0
1
10
1

40
13
2
31
04

1
01
1
0
62
72
4
4
3

73
6
11
6
53
8
2
9
61
22
3
2
01
43
04
1
2
04
1
04
0
21
0
5
```

Comment: Neat language! :)

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>7</s> 2 bytes

```
êê
```

[Run it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=6uo=&input=InJhY2VjYXIi)

#### Old solution:

```
U¥UwU¥U
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@x96aGloOYj4/18JzlYCAA)

#### Explanation

```
U¥UwU¥U
U¥        U is the input, ¥ is a shortcut for == 
  Uw      w is a reverse function.
    U¥U   This calculates U == U (always true), but the result is ignored
          because w does not look at its arguments.
```

Japt doesn't escape functions unless a closing parenthesis (or space) is reached.

This can be re-written: `U¥Uw(U¥U)`→`U¥Uw`→`U==Uw`. In Japt, the parenthesis left out at the begining and end of a function is auto-inserted.

Comment: It all makes sense, except if `w` is a function that takes no arguments, how does it apply to `U`? Is it something like `U.reverse()`?

Comment: @DLosc Correct. It reverses `U` in the same way as `U.reverse()`.

Answer (score 5):

## Java 8, <s>92</s> 90 bytes

This is a comment version. If a string contains its reverse, then it is a palindrome (`true`) otherwise it is not (`false`).

```java
s->s.contains(new StringBuffer(s).reverse())//))(esrever.)s(reffuBgnirtS wen(sniatnoc.s>-s
```

---

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tU@9TsMwEJ6Tp7A62RJxH6CQoUPVhSkjYjDpOXJwzpbvnKpCffZgmrIwIBZuudP3d3ejmU0TIuB4el/cFENiMRZMZ3Ze24w9u4D6cB92dcxv3vWi94ZIPBuH4qOu7iCx4dLm4E5iKpTsODkcXl6FSQOpL2X1nfS4cg/7EDwYbIUVTws1Lek@IBczSYSzWFX7bC0kSUonmCERSKW2W6Uk0A3QimQCa/N@QJe4E2dASegMY@g1tQ0tVbUr27sLMUw6ZNaxBLNHabWJ0V/k5gjeB@/huFHqT9qbTvyo31z/99568rW@Lp8)

**Update**

- **-2** [18-04-05] Switched to contains. Thanks to [*@Kevin Cruijssen*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/110582/im-a-palindrome-are-you/110667?noredirect=1#comment390293_110667)!
- **-2** [17-02-20] Removed `;`'s
- **-16** [17-02-22] Auto convert

Comment: This code is not a lambda expression.

Comment: @Jakob I thought it was. If you were to use the lambda, you would probably want a leading and trailing newline. (I added a tio link)

Comment: Yeah, my complaint was that the line comment makes the submission more than just a lambda expression, and thus not valid as a lambda solution. Don't worry about it for now; I'll probably eventually make a meta post to gather consensus.

Comment: @Jakob Lambda solutions can sometimes have [extraneous code](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6940/43214), which is why I think it is valid. But if you aren't sold, a meta post wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Well, the post you reference addresses multiple lambda expressions in a single solution, not code outside the expressions themselves (the author's intent in the last part is just to make function `g` available to `x`, not to allow extra code). At least that's the way I see it.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but you can golf 2 bytes by changing it to `s->s.contains(new StringBuffer(s).reverse())//))(esrever.)s(reffuBgnirtS wen(sniatnoc.s>-s`. [Try it online **90 bytes**.](https://tinyurl.com/ycwa96ff)

Answer (score 5):

## Dyalog APL, 6 bytes

```apl
⌽≡⊢⊢≡⌽
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HP3kedCx91LQIhIKNn7/@0R20THvX2Peqb6un/qKv50HrjR20TgbzgIGcgGeLhGfw/TUE9MSlZnQtCJyWqAwA)

Comment: This is the "correct" answer (as it works on all arrays), but for this particular challenge specification (argument is always a string), `⌷≡⌽⌽≡⌷` or `+≡⌽⌽≡+` works too while also being visually palindromic.

Answer (score 5):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 9 bytes

```
[:-.|.-:[
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8F2JT0F9TRbK3UdBQMFKyDW1VNwDvJxW1pakqZrsTLaSlevRk_XKhrCv2mnyZWanJGvkKagnpiUnJSojsRF5lVUViE4cEPUIaYsWAChAQ)

Lolwut. I was fiddling with various arrangements and adverb trains until I realized `[:` in trains is a thing, and `-.` (boolean negation) is perfectly OK thanks to the permissive output format. Returns 0 if the input is palindrome and 1 otherwise.

```
[: -. (|. -: [)
       |. -: [   Reverse matches identity (classic palindrome check)
[: -.            Boolean negation on the result
```

---

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 11 bytes

```
]&.|:-:|.&]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8F2JT0F9TRbK3UdBQMFKyDW1VNwDvJxW1pakqZrsTpWTa_GSteqRk8tFiJy00GTKzU5I18hTUE9MSk5KVEdiYvMq6isQnCQjFGHmLNgAYQGAA)

Wins against the existing [comment abuse solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/110774/78410). Uses a similar trick to [this answer to "I reverse the source, you reverse the input!"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/194789/78410).

Many of J's built-ins have inflections `.` and `:`, which are always treated as the suffix of a larger token. So the function above tokenizes as `] &. |: -: |. & ]`. And `&.` and `&` are conjunctions, which consume two things on both sides to form a single verb. Finally, `verb1 verb2 verb3` is a verb train; when given an argument `y`, it evaluates to `(verb1 y) verb2 (verb3 y)`.

```
] &. |: -: |. & ]
] &. |:             Identity under transpose: returns the input unchanged
           |. & ]   Reverse over identity: returns the input reversed
        -:          Match: tests if the two sides are identical
```

Comment: This is beautiful

Answer (score 4):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + Unix utilities, 49 bytes

```bash
[ "$1" = "`rev<<<$1`" ] # ] "`1$<<<ver`" = "1$" [
```

Input is passed as an argument.

Output is returned in the result code -- 0 for a palindrome, 1 for a non-palindrome.

*Maybe someone can do better and not just rely on a comment to make the code itself palindromic.*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@x@toKRiqKRgq6CUUJRaZmNjo2KYoKQQq6AMxEoJhipAkbLUogSwCkMVJYXo////5@WXKCQqFCTmZOalFOXnpgIA)

Comment: `[[ $1 = \`rev<<<$1\` ]]` is shorter. (Bash `[[` syntax, no quote needed)

Comment: @Arthur2e5 I tried out your suggestion, but I think the quotes around `rev<<<$1` are needed even in the `[[...]]` solution. Test it with input string `'[$]]$['` (which is a palindrome). With those quotes added in to make it work, your solution is the same length as my solution.

Comment: Great catch! I forgot that the RHS of `==` in `[[` would be interpreted as a `case`-like pattern.

Comment: @Arthur2e5 I still think there's probably some clever way to make this shorter.

Comment: Will this still work if there are newlines in the input? I think you need rev|tac instead of just rev.

Comment: @b_jonas The requirements specifically say that the input won't contain newlines. In the 3rd bullet under Clarifications: "Specifically, the input S will only contain printable ASCII characters (including space, but not including newline)."

Comment: Ah, thank you.  I indeed missed that part of the spec.

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript, 64 bytes

```
f=s=>s==[...s].reverse().join``//``nioj.)(esrever.]s...[==s>=s=f
```

Call function `f` with string

```
f("abba") // returns true
f("abab") // returns false
```

Comment: Your source code is not a palindrome!

Comment: @seshoumara Updated the code

Comment: Now it's fine. Maybe mention the return value if the string is not a palindrome, just for completion sake.

Comment: @apsillers thank you I edited the answer.

Comment: There is no function `f`, your code doesn't assign your arrow function to a variable so it can't be called

Comment: @spex anonymous functions are fine to be used

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista My comment wasn't about anonymous functions, it's that he was saying to call the function with `f` when at the time it didn't exist. The answer has since been updated and there is now a function `f` and my comment is now outdated.

Comment: @spex but that made him lose 4 bytes of his answer... I read the edit logs before replying to you, it's ok to do that

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista Like I said, I'm not against him using an anonymous function. I was against him saying "Call function `f` with string" when that was impossible. If he had simply changed the usage instructions that would have been a good fix.

Answer (score 4):

## Java - <s>171</s> <s>169</s> 160 bytes

```
int q(String s){return s.equals(new StringBuffer(s).reverse().toString())?1:2;}//};2:1?))(gnirtSot.)(esrever.)s(reffuBgnirtS wen(slauqe.s nruter{)s gnirtS(q tni
```

The comment at the end is to make it a palindrome.
Returns `P(alindrome)` when the input is palindrome and `N(ot)` when not.

Ungolfed version:

```
int q(String s) {
    return s.equals(new StringBuffer(s).reverse().toString()) ? 'P' : 'N';
}//};'N':'P'?))(gnirtSot.)(esrever.)s(reffuBgnirtS wen(slauqe.s nruter{)s gnirtS(q tni
```

2 bytes saved thanks to @DLosc

Thanks to @Olivier Grégoire for pointing out the incorrect amount of bytes! Fixed now

Comment: I believe you can save some bytes by returning `int`s instead of `char`s.

Comment: I don't know how do check your byte count, but you have 160 bytes, not 161.

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by returning 80 for `'P'` and 78 for `'N'` or use different chars to save even more bytes.

Comment: You can save even more bytes by doing `new StringBuffer(s).reverse()+""` instead of `new StringBuffer(s).reverse().toString()`

Comment: any reason you're returning an `int` instead of `bool`?

Comment: Definitely good to have Java answers, and this is in the same spirit as many other answers here, but I can't help but question whether this is valid as a method solution since the comment appears outside the method definition.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
ḂŒŒḂ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjqajk45OAlL///9XT0xKTkpUBwA)

Although this loses to the modern [`UƑU`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166925/85334), I figured it may be of historical interest to note that [Dennis's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/110583/85334) could have been only 4 bytes. Thanks to [a quirk of the parser](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/blob/c6ac722a4d2c7422c79ac4eeaa0c4abdad5fc16a/jelly.py#L589), any undefined characters--such as `Œ` outside a valid digraph--act equivalent to *two* newlines; as such, removing the newline yields a functionally identical solution (if not particularly forward-compatible, should `ŒŒ` ever hypothetically be added).

Answer (score 3):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 5 bytes

```
;R=R;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#@28dZBtk/f@/UmJSYpISAA)

The truthy output is `[1]\n[1]`, and the falsey output is `[]\n[]` (in both outputs, `\n` represents a literal newline).

Explanation:

```
;R=R;
;R=    duplicate input, reverse one copy, test equality (the main palindrome-testing part)
   R   range(1, x+1) - if palindrome, this pushes [1], else it pushes []
    ;  duplicate
```

Comment: Why don't you just do [this](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#@28dZPv/v1JiUmKSEgA)?

Comment: @LeakyNun it has to be a palindrome

Answer (score 3):

## C++, 154 Bytes

```
int m(){std::string g,p="";g=p;std::reverse(p.begin(),p.end());return g==p;}//};p==g nruter;))(dne.p,)(nigeb.p(esrever::dts;p=g;""=p,g gnirts::dts{)(m tni
```

I have to say, the reverse statement was costly, but I can't imagine much I can do to change that. Being able to cut out the std:: symbols would save me around 10 characters, but "using namespace std;" is quite a few more.

I suppose C++ wasn't really meant for brevity.

Answer (score 3):

### Prolog, 44 bytes

```
p-->[]|[_]|[E],p,[E].%.]E[,p,]E[|]_[|][>--p
```

This uses definite clause grammars. It is actually a full context free grammar:

```
p -->
      []            % the empty string
   |                % or
      [_]           % a one character string
   |                % or
      [E],          % one character, followed by
      p,            % a palindrome, followed by
      [E].          % that same character
```

Usage:

```
?- phrase(p,"reliefpfeiler").
true 

?- phrase(p,"re").
false.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), <s>2</s> 3 bytes

```
x=x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/?fbclid=IwAR2r_O3zVyorhM34NgYDdbci5cUq7pHgcBtquK0m_4L2meadMTYfQvWy6Dc##y00syUjPz0n7/7/CtuL/f/WixOTU5MQidS71vPw83YLEnMy8lKL83FSgQG5iSmKu@n8A)

### Explanation

Nothing fancy here, just some usage of implicit input. `x` reverses strings. Since the stack is empty, the input is reversed and placed on the stack. `=` checks for equality for the top two elements on the stack. Since the stack has only one element, the other element is fetched from the input, which is the original string. If they are equal, we get `1`, otherwise we get a `0`. `x` also works on integers, but since both `0` and `1` are 1-digit numbers, they remain unchanged.

EDIT: made the code a palindrome thanks to Lyxal's comment.

Comment: `Additionally, the program or function you write must be a palindrome itself (i.e. its source code must be palindromic), making this a restricted-source challenge` - `x=` is not a palindrome

Comment: `x=x` works for 3 bytes

Comment: @Lyxal I need to read the specification more closely, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @maxb Completely unrelated to this challenge, but MathGolf doesn't have a `count` builtin, does it?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen you mean a count of occurrences (like Python's `lst.count(x)`)? Unfortunately that's not included as of now. I haven't really had time to focus on the language in a while, but there are some unused bytes which could be used for new operators if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @maxb Yeah, that was indeed what I meant. I also couldn't really come up with a (short) alternative to do the count manually with the current operations available. Ah well, then I'll just skip that challenge for MathGolf. It does sound like a useful builtin to be added in the future perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

## Dyalog APL, 21 Bytes

I decided to avoid a comment-based solution, and ended up with something pretty ugly. Instead of commenting out the second half of my code, I keep it in and allow the resulting syntax error to be part of my output.

```
A←⍞⋄0∊A=⌽A⋄A⌽=A∊0⋄⍞←A
```

This prompts the user to enter a string, and prints

```
0
SYNTAX ERROR: The function requires a left argument
      A←⍞ ⋄ 0∊A=⌽A ⋄ A⌽=A∊0 ⋄ ⍞←A
```

If the input is a palindrome, and prints

```
1
SYNTAX ERROR: The function requires a left argument
      A←⍞ ⋄ 0∊A=⌽A ⋄ A⌽=A∊0 ⋄ ⍞←A
```

If the input is not a palindrome.

A simple comment based solution would be to replace the middle character (`⋄`) with the comment symbol (`⍝`):

```
A←⍞⋄0∊A=⌽A⍝A⌽=A∊0⋄⍞←A
```

This does the same as above but doesn't include the syntax error in the output.

Here's an ungolfed version:

```
A←⍞          ⍝ prompt user for input, store in variable A
⋄             ⍝ statement separator 
0∊A=⌽A       ⍝ return '0' if A is equal to A reversed (`⌽A`). Otherwise return '1' 
⋄             ⍝ statement separator
A⌽=A∊0⋄⍞←A   ⍝ reverse of preceding code, throws a syntax error
```

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 13 bytes

```
l_W%=e#e=%W_l
```

### Explanation:

```
l_W%=e#e=%W_l
l_            e#Read input twice
  W%          e#Reverse one input
    =         e#Test for equality
     e#e=%W_l e#Comment to be a palindrome
```

### Example:

```
> l_W%=e#e=%W_l
l_W%=e#e=%W_l
1

> l_W%=e#e=%W_l
Hi
0

> l_W%=e#e=%W_l
hh
1
```

Comment: Try this: `l_W%#e#%W_l`

Answer (score 2):

## J, 15 bytes, 15 characters

```
-:|.NB. .BN.|:-
```

Returns 1 if palindrome, 0 if not.

**Output:**

```
   f '())('
1
   f 'nope'
0
```

**Explanation:**

```
-:    NB. "Match" verb, checks for equality
|.    NB. Reverses the string
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <strike>39</strike> 35 chars

```
->s{s.reverse==s}#}s==esrever.s{s>-
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Our usual policy (which is also explicitly affirmed in this challenge) is that answers must be either a *full program* (with input and output) or a *function*. I'm not super familiar with Ruby, but your code looks like a *snippet* instead (it's just an expression, and assumes input pre-stored in the `s` variable). If you change it so it's either a function or a full program, it will be a valid answer.

Comment: @DLosc Sure, thanks, I made it a function

Comment: Then you can remove the () around s and save 4 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## Golfscript, 11 bytes

Bonus for the bytecount being a palindrome as well.

```
.-1%=#=%1-.
```

Duplicate, reverse, compare. Outputs `1` for palindromes and `0` for non-palindromes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-n`, 31 bytes

```ruby
p$_==$_.reverse#esrever._$==_$p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0Al3tZWJV6vKLUstag4VTm1GMzSi1extY1XKfj/PzEpOSnxX35BSWZ@XvF/3TwA)

A full program with implicit input (`-n`) turns out to be slightly shorter than lambda.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
UƑU
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/02MTQ/0f3HG5/1LQmC4gfNcxR0LVTeNQwN/L//2il9IwsJR0FpcSk5OSkRBALpB5EFyUmpyYnFhUjsZViAQ)

Added for the sake of completeness. This uses the fairly new quick `Ƒ`, which checks whether the argument is the same as the result of the atom being applied. Here, the atom is `U`, which reverses the argument. The quicklink `UƑ` returns either **1** for palindromes, or **0** otherwise. The second `U` has no effect on either integer, so leaves it as is.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 71 bytes

```r
any(rev(x<-utf8ToInt(scan(,"")))-x)#)x-)))"",(nacs(tnIoT8ftu-<x(ver(yna
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rcyhDQAhDADAXfqCNgGPYAE8CxACsiRQSJme/yHenbpxb@aDo27U4JY0n3pkwVkyowUgIqf0kLpPABY5l4nCsSffZLmguOvAw/manyJzXw)

Comments to make it a palindrome. Returns `FALSE` if the input is a palindrome, `TRUE`  otherwise. Could save 2 bytes off the palindrome using `sd` if we were guaranteed to have an input size >1.

Interpreting liberally this portion of the asnwer

> if you treat the input as a sequence of bytes rather than a sequence of characters, your program will still likely comply with the specification

would lead to:

#### [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 43 bytes

```r
any(x<-scan()-rev(x))#))x(ver-)(macs-<x(yna
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzGvUqPCRrc4OTFPQ1O3KLVMo0JTU1lTs0KjLLVIV1MjNzG5WNemQqMyL/G/pYWCoZGCmSkIARmWFv8B)

Answer (score 2):

### [W](https://github.com/myu-sername/w), 3 bytes

Pretty trivial, reverse & check equality & reciprocal. (I definitely beat Jelly by tying with Pyth.)

```
_=_
```

### Explanation

```
_   Reverse the implicitly inputted string
 =  Check whether this reversed string is equal to the original string
  _ Negate this string
```

Answer (score 2):

## Google Sheets, <s>171 167</s> 163

Input is in `A1`.

```
=-IFERROR(JOIN(,ArrayFormula(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1),1,LEN(A1),-1),1)))=""&A1,1)&"&)1,1A&""=)))1,)1-,)1A(NEL,1,)1A(NEL(ECNEUQES,1A(DIM(alumroFyarrA,(NIOJ(RORREFI-=
```

- Palindrome: `-1&)1A&"=)))1,)1-,)1A(NEL,1,)1A(NEL(ECNEUQES,1A(DIM(alumroFyarrA,(NIOJ(RORREFI-=`
- Not: `0&)1A&"=)))1,)1-,)1A(NEL,1,)1A(NEL(ECNEUQES,1A(DIM(alumroFyarrA,(NIOJ(RORREFI-=`

### How it works:

1. Compare a string with its reverse. I thought it necessary to handle the empty string as well, so I added `IFERROR()` for the `MID()`.
2. Coerce to number with `-`. 1 becomes -1, 0 stays 0.
3. The only requirement was two distinct outputs, so just concatenate the program's reverse to the end.
4. We also exploit the fact that Sheets closes quotes and parens at the end.
5. The center of the palindrome is the `&"&`

Comment: As of now, Sequence appears to have a bug where I can't omit the second argument with a negative step.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
RQR
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/KDDo//@ixJJihZzMslSF/DyFvHyF1LLMHIXiksQiAA)

```
RQR  # full program
 Q   # is...
     # implicit input...
 Q   # equal to...
     # implicit input...
R    # reversed...
 Q   # ? (1 if yes, 0 if no)
  R  # reverse top of stack (no-op since both 1 and 0 are palindromes)
     # implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## x86_64 machine code, 49 bytes

Uses System V ABI calling convention (specifically first arg in RDI, return in RAX, DF cleared by caller).

Hexdump:

```
00000000: 31c0 575e 31c9 f7d1 f2ae 4883 ef02 803e  1.W^1.....H....>
00000010: 0074 05a6 74f4 ffc0 c3c0 fff4 74a6 0574  .t..t.......t..t
00000020: 003e 8002 ef83 48ae f2d1 f7c9 315e 57c0  .>....H.....1^W.
00000030: 31                                       1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVPBbtswDL37K4hgh3azO6dJ0y5BDx2GAT3tMGCXrjAUS@40yFIqyYu9Yd@eUaJaO5kPhEQ9Pj4@ycw50W7VUGjm2sPDVnoHq@Vjlm0gZKBohGpWSyjMjimpuTWtuDAw2SAKwYofQaYAk2VO1F4aDRfWcOZZBvghYg18C7NJ1ZkVvjyfvZxXSmgQzx28gSLss3igja9ei3EDDE4o5okiIY9oUm6iyYveR/iTMlumoHKeWcpktF7HTd3u4HlvLIcH63aPOVzCBkTPaq8G8HsDzD65osCUqDvPtkqA81bqJ2CagxfOp31ka80vsFwmFmuNrWrDBdzCZTz/qQUyyaTjqGIU8W6@esRyHMVgC@yP7U8b1UypmKwmLm1ANhPXcrCsx9YlOWwsCNbnIZCW3zAIR7bhuzBx9SrJoaQXV0edfT61n2jQQKF5zGH7LEuk62Ou/3heOLKxeFIShM6DCYOr9lZ6cWxWPPLcdOQkooIhNGePg0YQhtNbQCuC/WvMM@e6Vjg6h3jOlBWMD@i8P1ayKpOU17tLHQ8buNe7Dgl1p1TBhZItiuVQ/2D2LUgdRKC7XzofUeX7eUziFWzgLin49Pm2hLMdPkkwDXwd3De4@3h/joh7lIe/svYSew0wk9qDdFW6gnTNZ9QLH8c5/Pk7y05eBZmKf1XZL@Y5xroM8eo6RpGP@Q8hNjHPY6a5DJFFzPImxJtFDt8jYdmLJmTKiLmJnIuILOP6ehnXV5FhNWYais2opJ5wUoZOCUlVxEBsiXnSkbqTElI11UnKaQqaKE13PU5NDpAb5AwpWcwPh8NsX9vFsrTelsuFrfezfw)

Explanation:

```
0000000000401020 <test_palindrome>:
  401020:   31 c0                   xor    eax,eax ; clear eax
  401022:   57                      push   rdi
  401023:   5e                      pop    rsi ; copy rdi to rsi

  ; get end of string (by SCASing rdi to find 0)
  401024:   31 c9                   xor    ecx,ecx
  401026:   f7 d1                   not    ecx
  401028:   f2 ae                   repnz scas al,BYTE PTR es:[rdi]

  ; addr of start is in rsi, addr of end (past \0) is 
  ; in rdi, so we subtract 2 from rdi. Thankfully this is needed below too,
  ; so we can combine the two steps into one.

  ; Now, we loop, incrementing rsi and decrementing rdi until [rsi] == '\0'
000000000040102a <testp_loop>:
  40102a:   48 83 ef 02             sub    rdi,0x2 ; Shortest way to do this?

  40102e:   80 3e 00                cmp    BYTE PTR [rsi],0x0 ; [rsi] == '\0'?
  401031:   74 05                   je     401038 <retl> ; If so, str is a palindrome (ret0)

  ; Check that [rsi] == [rdi]
  401033:   a6                      cmps   BYTE PTR ds:[rsi],BYTE PTR es:[rdi] ; Auto increments rsi and rdi, so rdi needs subtracting by 2.
  401034:   74 f4                   je     40102a <testp_loop> ; If so, keep looping.

  ; Otherwise, str is not a palindrome (ret1)
  401036:   ff c0                   inc    eax

0000000000401038 <retl>:
  401038:   c3                      ret    

  ; <nonsense to make code a palindrome>
  401039:   c0 ff f4 74 a6 05 74 00 3e 80 02 ef 83 48 ae f2 d1 f7 c9 31 5e 57 c0 31
```

Answer (score 1):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 17 bytes

```
;?A=_fA|#|Af_=A?;
```

Uses a boring comment-like ttrick to make the code a palindrome. Explanation:

```
;         Get a string literal from the cmd prompt
?         Print -1 for true and 0 for false in the following comparison
A=        Is A equal to
_fA|      A reversed?

#         Start a 'silent' string literal: This only forces the creation of string B
          with the following text, but doesn't inject a reference to B$ here.
|Af_=A?;  Code, reversed, as a string literal.
```

Answer (score 1):

## AppleScript, 146 bytes

*clutch*

```
set x to(display dialog""default answer"")'s characters--
x=reverse of x--x fo esrever=x
--sretcarahc s')""rewsna tluafed""golaid yalpsid(ot x tes
```

This should be fairly obvious.

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 104 bytes

```
(lambda(s)(format t"~:[F~;T~]"(equal(reverse s)s)));;)))s)s esrever(lauqe("]~T;~F[:~"t tamrof()s(adbmal(
```

Abusing idea for commenting out part of code from comments under question.

Answer (score 1):

**Javascript, 78 bytes**

```
(s=>s==s.split('').reverse().join(''))//))''(nioj.)(esrever.)''(tilps.s==s>=s(
```

This is the classic `.split`, `.reverse` and `.join` routine.

Another (longer, but I like it more) 104 bytes solution would be

```
(s=>!s.split('').find((a,i,l)=>a!==l[l.length-i-1]))//))]1-i-htgnel.l[l==!a>=)l,i,a((dnif.)''(tilps.s!>=s(
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - 3 bytes

An alternative 3 byte solution. Palindromes give `-1` and non-palindromes give `0`.

```
_q_
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=_q_&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22amanaplanacanalpanama%22%0A%22blahblah%22%0A%22racecar%22%0A%22hello%22&debug=0).

A few more 3 byte solutions:

```
_/_
_}_
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scala - 58 bytes

```
def p(s:String)=s.reverse==s//s==esrever.s=)gnirtS:s(p fed
```

Example -

```
p("abba") //returns true

p("aabb") //returns false
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java (with regex), 134 bytes

```
s->s.matches("|(?:(.)(?<=(?=^.*?(\\1\\2?)$).*))+(?<=(?=^\\2$).*)")//)")*.)$2\\^=?(=<?(+))*.)$)?2\\1\\(?*.^=?(=<?().(:?(|"(sehctam.s>-s
```

[Credits where due](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664881/how-does-this-java-regex-detect-palindromes)

### Testing

```
import java.util.function.*;

class Ideone {
  static Predicate<String> isPalindrome = 
    s->s.matches("|(?:(.)(?<=(?=^.*?(\\1\\2?)$).*))+(?<=(?=^\\2$).*)")//)")*.)$2\\^=?(=<?(+))*.)$)?2\\1\\(?*.^=?(=<?().(:?(|"(sehctam.s>-s
    ;

  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    testPalindrome("", true);
    testPalindrome("x", true);
    testPalindrome("xx", true);
    testPalindrome("xy", false);
    testPalindrome("xyx", true);
    testPalindrome("xxx", true);
    testPalindrome("xxyx", false);
    testPalindrome("racecar", true);
    testPalindrome("step on no pets", true);
    testPalindrome("aManaPlanaCanalPanaMa", true);
    testPalindrome("this is impossible", false);
  }

  static void testPalindrome(String s, boolean expected) {
    if (isPalindrome.test(s) == expected) {
      System.out.println("OK");
    } else {
      System.out.printf("NOK: str=\"%s\", expected=%b%n", s, expected);
    }
  }
}
```

[Test it yourself!](http://ideone.com/ZjdClm)

Comment: This code is not a lambda expression.

Comment: @Jakob No? Why not? It works as a lambda, though.

Comment: My complaint is with the comment. Seems to me that having anything outside the lambda expression makes it an invalid lambda solution. In particular, this solution cannot be embedded in a program the way a lambda expression can (e.g. with code appearing after it on the same line). See also [the grammar for a lambda expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-LambdaExpression), which most lambda solutions adhere to, but this doesn't.

Comment: Why can't it be embedded? `stream.map(a->a//comment<new_line>).collect(...)` (replace <new_line> with an actual new line) works well! Just because 99.99% of lambdas adhere to that principle doesn't make this one invalid. Does it? A lambda isn't defined from how it appears in the source, but how it's compiled, and this one compiles just fine, unless proven otherwise.

Comment: Well, my concern is not that it doesn't work or that it can't be embedded into a full program; it's that it violates the format of a lambda expression solution. I think I'll create a meta post where this discussion can continue.

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 50 bytes

Failed to *not* write a comment based solution so this is it:

```
(s:String)=>s.reverse==s//s==esrever.s>=)gnirtS:s(
```

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 61 bytes

```
(lambda(n)(equal(reverse n)n));))n)n esrever(lauqe()n(adbmal(
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pYvLDcAgDMVWiTi9N0OnoSUHJIj4lK6foq7Qiw@WfZU8m6ONbLfAUWI9U4QR2lcsGPromCpGIw9umuj87G5XV9AQ01l36@HXHoT0Fw)

Outputs `T` when the string is palindrome, `NIL` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 1 byte

```
₽
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//UdPe///LitPLAQ)

```
   implicit input
₽  palindromic test
   implicit output
```

### Previous answer

before I knew that 1 byte solutions were allowed

```
₽ƥƥ₽
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//UdPeY0uPLQVS//@XAQA)

```
₽ checks for palindromicness (is that a word?)
ƥ prints the answer
ƥ prints nothing
₽ checks the palindromicness of nothing
```

Comment: [1 byte](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//UdPe///LAA). I don't think it ever says that solutions have to be more than a single byte.

Comment: Oh that's weird. I could have sworn it did, but maybe it was a different challenge.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 bytes

```
êê
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=6uo=&input=IurqIg==)

`ê` on its own in Japt creates a palindrome but, when passed a string as an argument (which the second `ê` is implicitly cast to in this case), it instead tests if a string is palindromic.

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 13 bytes

```
L,dbR=;=Rbd,L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99HJyUpyNbaNigpRcfn////RYnJqcmJRQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 118 bytes

Can sadly not come up with any solution without the boring comment approach.

```c
f(char*s){char*t=s+strlen(s);for(;*s&&*s++==*--t;);s=!*s;}//};s*!=s;);t--*==++s*&&s*;(rof;)s(nelrts+s=t*rahc{)s*rahc(f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU47DsIwDJ3JKUIlKsdpxI6Vm7CEtCmVIEWxxVL17CWUhel95efoxhi3LUG8h4Jslh3Fs2UpjyEDG0pzAUJuW2RrvUfnhAyxPyLTej6vxHj0XC1xDr23lrFtGQnKnMgw5OFRpB70giXc42J4R0jbe556Pe7buo6rRR1eZcqSoDnxRZ/6a246zZ1O9Q9DalWqpvoZpgx7e4RGBpamZl8ebjHewp/6iXX7AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Reflections](https://thewastl.github.io/Reflections/), 125 bytes

```
  _1=1\ /1#\ /+#_ 
      >~<  >~<
        (0//0)
      \ / >_ / _> / \      
)0//0(        
<~>  <~>      
 _#+/ \#1/ \1=1_
```

[Test it!](https://thewastl.github.io/Reflections/reflections.html##ICBfMT0xXCAvMSNcIC8rI18gCiAgICAgID5+PCAgPn48CiAgICAgICAgKDAvLzApCiAgICAgIFwgLyA+XyAvIF8+IC8gXCAgICAgIAopMC8vMCggICAgICAgIAo8fj4gIDx+PiAgICAgIAogXyMrLyBcIzEvIFwxPTFfICD/MP8w/zD/KCkpKA==)

Prints code point 0x04 as true, and nothing as false.
There are a few spaces after some lines.

#### Explanation

The relevant part of the code is:

```
  _1=1\ /1#\ /+#_
      >~<  >~<
        (0//0)
      \ / >_ /
```

- `_` reads a line
- `1=1` copies it to stack 1
- `>~<` creates a loop over the complete stack:

  - `(0` pushes the top item to stack 0
- now stack 0 contains the reverse, and stack 1 the original
- `1` moves stack 1 to mainstack
- `>~<` loops again:

  - `0)` takes the next character from reversed
  - `>_` if original and reversed character are not equal:

    - end the program by navigating downwards, leaving the field
- `+` produces the 4
- `_` prints corresponding character
- then the program stops (leaving the field to the right)

The rest is only for palindromic source. I know this is boring.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 29 bytes

```perl
$_=reverse=~$_#_$~=esrever=_$
```

Requres `-p0`. Outputs `1` if the input is a palindrome, empty otherwise.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3rYotSy1qDjVtk4lXjlepc42tRgsYhuv8v9/UWJyanJi0b/8gpLM/Lzi/7oFBgA)

---

**Perl 5, 33 bytes**

```perl
+$_=reverse=~$_+q+_$~=esrever=_$+
```

Commentless version, requires `-p0`. Outputs `1` if the input is a palindrome, `0` otherwise.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19bJd62KLUstag41bZOJV67UDtepc42tRgsZhuvov3/f1FicmpyYtG//IKSzPy84v@6BQYA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
Ṙ=Ṙ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLhuZg94bmYIiwiIiwiIl0=)

```
 =  # Equal to...
Ṙ   # Self reversed?
  Ṙ # Reverse the result
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 71 bytes

```
;=a=pP;=s'';Wp;=s+GpF1s=pSpF1''O?a s a?O''1FpSp=s1FpG+s=;pW;''s=;Pp=a=;
```

Input the string with a trailing newline.

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##rVhrc9s2Fv3eX0FzU4sQaVrOdLoT0bQm8dqZzDayN3br2ZWUGAQhiQ1FMnzYTiX2r6f3gi9QL6cz@8WSgIP7wrkP@Hf6QBMWe1F6FIQu/8Z8miTKvwNvNk8v4jiMFf6U8sBNFPFrmReAaxonvL0vnalQH7Ig9RbP427SmNPFkoVBksYZS8NYo2SZzr3ETMIsZtymOex40d3cS3kSUca1cn9BUzbXjj9qo/FkPBonsJ73J/rqH6OP42DS1cbB6gUh3WOSR5x/ht2Yp1kcKJLwUW@yWgWZ7@eFMMdgdo8sfZ4q1HZM/sSZJsGJVYrAI7Zt0wF@6csQW/puJpkDtmsU1Jg@D2bpnBh0xCYkT0Nw3AtmW63KcxEO5fa/1xc39mhiFaH6jfoZXyYpTT2mRHgLmkOWjrkRHmsKUXygMfjQs@ipEFPqt6iuF/4xW6yP6MSsZFneVGOktIflkq95nAUi7HH4qAT8sWBE7nInm21Z3@GdEGI2m4AbZguHxztw1Sbg3oShz2mwA1jv5iWrfoFgxNSviVeEbo1kSRahdEOI@uTSlALXCkclJVucKX8357Z5Uv5ugzbcqBZkGP/io3klgioeWE0DxsNp4bXkxuGhZDzwsfhWRQGF1yEoQ7LBn4rrTTbdXk7I6PXR/ybdY@Okpjw9PMQLRpmaequiNpK72SKqnbmvnHkh8jMn97mfzhtXDhpbDw9p69pmMk6RcQdtYF6QOcqSuYarxCpS5WL427sPV8P3F8Nbe5mXCfPO5UG6xoHn3B/Roz8@TfBv7@jVJwjBegCEUDA238cmD0HApnZ8xFFv6gGuCFGBw0CBud4sQDmSJ6MGM6mpWRi8A4UZ/BB6rtI7wPupLLeaBJXrsnb/a/A5CB8DxastUzot0zr37ZgLF0gVXym630uvsatvhhQCWqYLJeukKjcaTlHXlbhSnW84o1OpdJAcavBe@FEbvsj8vfBuG@56D7KXzRbeROsSKlHvaTo3gTcBk6Qeg9@7Lkk9p0EQpgqogjtRnK/KHzwOVTA1dP@m7kbhj/RZfSA@80NJXxQ@7tfXiF@tDjR62iPf5Xy3@x3e86coDJCkNOXCICUNoTYGfAZ8e@AKGMdjMNLfUUlO5XvbWW/OWqgW8RvaD6Eh7ue9VL1r4g/LkkoKzqOQVgmpKgi227UcUBGsEXVfZxDySuefCSULF2AmF0dMtQ7G3zwlBwfXquhAc3w2OEghx6ZSz1E7EwJzXDK@mXQHZHxybLwUtMJoALMcmUigAYeVYoihZjHcIVjtYFtiq1VH7eAX0rjUDK1Y9MCqhRcAk1zlSxYCoXjAwgyXudtXXixpfr@tpQv723lknPTIatVbq1nlgLCvZqET9yWgVLhZehDU6DJjHnEKvUeuQM8wvh619jK@RsmXCotld4VT1L35GrA@ze2Yf8m8mGvqNFGJscQRWWw50habe777KYpDxhNEXf46PL99dzW8aXrzJdSAfa1ZYklxwTCZ12JGjtTpxE1Ls6ol8WrQF1mnr0xyXDCG4zyN8zH@cGE@dk9ZNRu71Ww8tYVFZmUKKjuY7qDTew96dzBTaDzLFjhwvFi6@kmugBJlil5CR3WwkVq8COyU5NIdYyA0ZjgGXxspYImtjRUozqbF94AuuO0U30F1YrPN2VUc0EzTrFF1ZSmquIraUy8MNFWvpdbhcZRq5BRHqW6rhqLqjlnIqLu4rm7Upivnd85S00sEfw0Yl/JpqUqJ@cxLUi5cJEsI7Qn2quqBtPaW0NQhmKQsMhjyHEjUJ8pS/6sCvUBhcxrDL5hZ/DCYQU2yGoLQie1IGiEwdeeSr7ZMMniBao6UB0SuPc0YVbw3rK00UIeh8oCSoVBmvou2ChXuAdRKKasw4MSoQ6Beq4ZG7LPySaaqhmO/yaZTHpvU90OmwQDuhhgkqvWAET2YyA2gvANPSuKA4Z8tpoOrj5BxXDuBLix2xEvOxNy68yDx1XGgEsJsZia@By/EnqEcNZN9VWkYyWXLPhSWtVr31A/B159evvrp1c//fPnq565YjWnghgsMm3z@QjWofYYho63QNpDO6w5C6kQvwlta5cjdDQwYVGYWksxpHC7OgQHnoQuDZvl2Iv3KXPk6TVbiXqc4s8lGvhFGUnnpvFgqH5fir7x9L7brPtR2boej6n/EobIgmvzJW6/iEvagViDeWu0HUAv5S41Ej2VDqmSS0f9Cbp3V41sr2JVlSeqGWWo@xtC4QWCR58SgrZhdtQU1Wktp6ngsnocl2YBpgx3yKzYChPS3Yu6xN/5wT4x6ZpIt0YGiWESa68JGW/rWcv5oA4nvgm3I7gYS@/I25PEGUrwGtiB/3JQZbrfz4wZSTN1bkKc1sqZKdQQngvqIfOZs95nZrjOD3Wew5G89c1if0WiV163/0wzKY/1W5q2ePUb7zmZGWtKxYtfYFjBbgrVqCz5pVytQKT3v24lMzfJ97ti1fqcl/K4WvsTuabWS1iJr6baVzO8KEdD07TO6NVhs0/e30iERtMZuw2k90gws/9LPqoLR6r@UKGS1UtV21G5KBa5QUR16RpVru5uaa3DV6nGsH1AdpsrKBOhwRGd6Y5LuYi9uGsafHbnitZ/ugIPoVFUEJpaH0UvohN@@fbNsakfXlp10OtZdBJ/62@jyJLGjG/jodK4GVEkUOrjqdE4uYc1O4OOtnthWdGd1OvB5HYEE64f/l6C/AA)

In case you're curious, here's the non-palindromized version of the code:

```
;=a=pP;=s'';Wp;=s+GpF1s=pSpF1''O?a s
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##lVhrc9s2Fv3eX0FzU4sQaVrOdLoT0bQmce1MZhvZjd16diUlBkFIYkORDB@2U4n719N7wReol9MvlgQc3BfOfcB/0geasNiL0qMgdPk35tMkUf4TeLN5ehHHYazwp5QHbqKIX8u8AFzTOOHtfelMhfqQBam3eB53k8acLpYsDJI0zlgaxholy3TuJWYSZjHjNs1hx4vu5l7Kk4gyrpX7C5qyuXb8URuNJ@PROIH1vD/RV/8afRwHk642DlYvCOkekzzi/DPsxjzN4kCRhI96k9UqyHw/L4Q5BrN7ZOnzVKG2Y/InzjQJTqxSBB6xbZsO8EtfhtjSdzPJHLBdo6DG9HkwS@fEoCM2IXkaguNeMNtqVZ6LcCi3/72@uLFHE6sI1R/Uz/gySWnqMSXCW9AcsnTMjfBYU4jiA43Bh55FT4WYUr9Fdb3wj9lifUQnZiXL8qYaI6U9LJd8zeMsEGGPw0cl4I8FI3KXO9lsy/oO74QQs9kE3DBbODzegas2AfcmDH1Ogx3AejcvWfUrBCOmfk28InRrJEuyCKUbQtQnl6YUuFY4KinZ4kz5uzm3zZPydxu04Ua1IMP4Fx/NKxFU8cBqGjAeTguvJTcODyXjgY/FtyoKKLwOQRmSDf5UXG@y6fZyQkavj/436R4bJzXl6eEhXjDK1NRbFbWR3M0WUe3MfeXMC5GfObnP/XTeuHLQ2Hp4SFvXNpNxiow7aAPzgsxRlsw1XCVWkSoXwz/efbgavr8Y3trLvEyYdy4P0jUOPOf@iB799WmCf3tHrz5BCNYDIISCsfk@NnkIAja14yOOelMPcEWIChwGCsz1ZgHKkTwZNZhJTc3C4B0ozOCH0HOV3gHeT2W51SSoXJe1@9@Dz0H4GChebZnSaZnWuW/HXLhAqvhK0f1eeo1dfTOkENAyXShZJ1W50XCKuq7Elep8wxmdSqWD5FCD98KP2vBF5u@Fd9tw13uQvWy28CZal1CJek/TuQm8CZgk9Rj83nVJ6jkNgjBVQBXcieJ8Vf7icaiCqaH7D3U3Cn@kz@oD8ZkfSvqi8HG/vkb8anWg0dMe@S7nu93v8J4/RWGAJKUpFwYpaQi1MeAz4NsDV8A4HoOR/o5Kcirf2856c9ZCtYjf0H4IDXE/76XqXRN/WJZUUnAehbRKSFVBsN2u5YCKYI2o@zqDkFc6/0woWbgAM7k4Yqp1MP7hKTk4uFZFB5rjs8FBCjk2lXqO2pkQmOOS8c2kOyDjk2PjpaAVRgOY5chEAg04rBRDDDWL4Q7BagfbElutOmoHv5DGpWZoxaIHVi28AJjkKl@yEAjFAxZmuMzdvvJiSfP7bS1d2N/OI@OkR1ar3lrNKgeEfTULnbgvAaXCzdKDoEaXGfOIU@g9cgV6hvH1qLWX8TVKvlRYLLsrnKLuzdeA9Wlux/xL5sVcU6eJSowljshiy5G22Nzz3U9RHDKeIOry9@H57bur4U3Tmy@hBuxrzRJLiguGybwWM3KkTiduWppVLYlXg77IOn1lkuOCMRznaZyP8YcL87F7yqrZ2K1m46ktLDIrU1DZwXQHnd570LuDmULjWbbAgePF0tVPcgWUKFP0Ejqqg43U4kVgpySX7hgDoTHDMfjaSAFLbG2sQHE2Lb4HdMFtp/gOqhObbc6u4oBmmmaNqitLUcVV1J56YaCpei21Do@jVCOnOEp1WzUUVXfMQkbdxXV1ozZdOX9ylppeIvhrwLiUT0tVSsxnXpJy4SJZQmhPsFdVD6S1t4SmDsEkZZHBkOdAoj5RlvpfFegFCpvTGH7BzOKHwQxqktUQhE5sR9IIgak7l3y1ZZLBC1RzpDwgcu1pxqjivWFtpYE6DJUHlAyFMvNdtFWocA@gVkpZhQEnRh0C9Vo1NGKflU8yVTUc@002nfLYpL4fMg0GcDfEIFGtB4zowURuAOUdeFISBwz/bDEdXH2EjOPaCXRhsSNecibm1p0Hia@OA5UQZjMz8T14IfYM5aiZ7KtKw0guW/ahsKzVuqd@CL7@9PLVT69@/vfLVz93xWpMAzdcYNjk8xeqQe0zDBlthbaBdF53EFInehHe0ipH7m5gwKAys5BkTuNwcQ4MOA9dGDTLtxPpV@bK12myEvc6xZlNNvKNMJLKS@fFUvm4FH/l7XuxXfehtnM7HFV/E4fKgmjyJ2@9ikvYg1qBeGu1H0At5K81Ej2WDamSSUb/gtw6q8e3VrAry5LUDbPUfIyhcYPAIs@JQVsxu2oLarSW0tTxWDwPS7IB0wY75FdsBAjpb8XcY2/84Z4Y9cwkW6IDRbGINNeFjbb0reX80QYS3wXbkN0NJPblbcjjDaR4DWxB/rgpM9xu58cNpJi6tyBPa2RNleoITgT1EfnM2e4zs11nBrvPYMnfeuawPqPRKq9b/6cZlMf6rcxbPXuM9p3NjLSkY8WusS1gtgRr1RZ80q5WoFJ63rcTmZrl@9yxa/1OS/hdLXyJ3dNqJa1F1tJtK5nfFSKg6dtndGuw2Kbvb6VDImiN3YbTeqQZWP6ln1UFo9V/KVHIaqWq7ajdlApcoaI69Iwq13Y3NdfgqtXjWD@gOkyVlQnQ4YjO9MYk3cVe3DSM/3fkitd@ugMOolNVEZhYHkYvoRN@@/bNsqkdXVt20ulYdxF86m@jy5PEjm7go9O5GlAlUejgqtM5uYQ1O4GPt3piW9Gd1enA53UEEqwfvkvQ3w)

Comment: ... How does this not error???

Comment: @emanresuA How I understand it is that everything after the `O?a s` isn't evaluated because it is the last instruction the code runs (so there's no chance of any error occurring), so it doesn't matter what you put after the final instruction.

Comment: @emanresuA The entire program is a single prefix expression. Once a complete expression is formed, the parser simply stops there.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 33 bytes

```julia
!x=reverse(x)==x#x==)x(esrever=x!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/X7HCtii1LLWoOFWjQtPWtkK5wtZWs0IjtRgsaluh@N@hOCO/XEFRqSgxOTU5sUiJCyagoamhiczT1EDwCBqLUKr0HwA)

- A comment is used to make the source a palindrome
- Returns `true` for the empty string

Answer (score 0):

## [Python], 84 bytes

```python
lambda s:list(s)==list(reversed(list(s)))#)))s(tsil(desrever(tsil==)s(tsil:s adbmal
```

Pretty simple, take the string s, convert it into a list of chars and then compare that against the reversed list of chars generated from the same string.

Comment: This answer is invalid because it isn't a palindrome itself.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem missed that caveat, but fixed now, unfortunately ugly. Helps clarify some of the other answers though ;P

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 109 bytes

```
INPUT P$WHILE LEN(P$)>1P=P+(POP(P$)!=SHIFT(P$))WEND?!P'P!?DNEW))P$(TFIHS=!)$P(POP(+P==P1>)$P(NEL ELIHW$P TUPNI
```

Could definitely be shorter...

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5, 69 bytes

`$_=<>;chop;print 1 if reverse eq$_#_$qe esrever fi 1 tnirp;pohc;><=_$`

Takes input via STDIN. Prints `1` if the input is a palendrome, otherwise exits.

Comment: A couple of hints: you could save quite a few bytes by just printing the boolean returned by `eq` directly; and you could request input with no trailing newline to avoid the need to call `chop`.

Answer (score 0):

### REXX, 78 bytes

```
arg a
b="say a=reverse(a)"
interpret b
exit
tixe
b terpretni
")a(esrever=a yas"=b
a gra
```

I thought that early exit would leave the mirrored program uninterpreted, but at least Regina REXX complains about unbalanced parentheses, hence the INTERPRET workaround.

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 32 bytes

*Just another "boring" solution but in Kotlin :))*

```
s.reversed()==s//s==)(desrever.s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY/BCsIwDIbvfYqyU3vZ7sMK@gSCTxBoHKVdOpIpDPHZa6cnLzWQQ5LvJ3wxrylQud1JzxDIAE8y6hMzbIfryoGmo9VPpWstdVoTmSAXqBnPeUbTRdggdtY2kJRTqN2GpGd8IAt6Y52TYRDnrPEon3Uv7TTlBXfipdSu8nOsPl8TO55zTgikXfn3rpQ3)

Answer (score 0):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 5 bytes

```
]iei]
```

Returns `-1\n-1` for true, `0\n0` for false.

### Explained

```
]iei]
]       # Duplicate the top of the stack.
 i      # Reverse the duplicate
  e     # Are they equal? 1 if true, 0 if false.
   i    # Inverse calculates n*-1. Redunant.
    ]   # Duplicate. Redundant.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6/z82MzUz9v///7mpqbkA)

Answer (score 0):

## BASH, 52 bytes

```
[ "`rev<<<$1`" = "$1" ];$?$;] "1$" = "`1$<<<ver`" [
```

success output (run as `palpal.bash`:

```
~/workspace/golf $ bash palpal.bash "$(cat palpal.bash)"
palpal.bash: line 1: 0$: command not found
palpal.bash: line 1: 1$: command not found
palpal.bash: line 1: ]: command not found
```

failure output:

```
~/workspace/golf $ bash palpal.bash "hello"
palpal.bash: line 1: 1$: command not found
palpal.bash: line 1: 1$: command not found
palpal.bash: line 1: ]: command not found
```

notice that first output line has either a `1` or `0` which are the return code of the actual palindrome check.

It's not much better than using a comment for the second half

Answer (score 0):

## C++ (gcc), 138 bytes

```c++
[](auto s){return equal(s.begin(),s.begin()+s.size()/2,s.rbegin());}//};))(nigebr.s,2/)(ezis.s+)(nigeb.s,)(nigeb.s(lauqe nruter{)s otua(][
```

Lambda using a builtin to check if the argument is palindromic. To make it palindromic, I had to add the entire source, reversed, in a comment. Not very creative, I know. Note that clang will not compile this.

Try it online [here](https://tio.run/##zZDNCoJAFIXX@RSDEdyLpuBSqxcxF@N4lQEbdX42ic9u0w/RrpbtDh/f4R6uGMd9J8TKnR1Yy45rWcEjG5w1WacVo8nxHkxSUycVYPxOkUmMvBJgmnmoXxSLJU2XAhGU7KjWiYmzFIGu0uvRi3r4TtBzNxFT2lnSMxo2WMehKtciCLZSid41xA7C2EYOpw9irJaqOwUXfj/L5mAzemBbCHfNWYUxa8F38vzpQcjrmofo930Xf/VE86P6P199zl3WGw).

Answer (score 0):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 31 bytes

```
iEv
?;>l2(q1h{-
-{h1q(2l>;?
vEi
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/P9O1jMve2i7HSKPQMKNal0u3OsOwUMMox87anqvMNZOgAgA)

```
iEv
?;>l2(q1h{-

iEv
i    Take input as a char
 E   If the last input was EOF, pop and execute next; otherwise, skip 1
iEv  Take all input and move to next line

>l2(q1h{-?;
 l2(         Is the stack length < 2? (1 if yes, 0 otherwise)
    q        If not, skip 2 commands (consume the top)
     1h      Print 1 and halt
       {     Rotate the stack (bottom goes to the top)
        -    Difference
         ?   If zero, skip one command (consume the top)
          ;  Halt without printing anything
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 110 bytes

```cs
s=>Console.Write(new string(s.Reverse().ToArray())==s)//)s==))(yarrAoT.)(esreveR.s(gnirts wen(etirW.elosnoC>=s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDPagJBDMbPO08RPM1QHB/AzoJ4bUGs4KH2EMa4HbpmaDJVluKzb0f2UiHkD/l98CVR5zELjT@auIO3QQudl@b/5F8Sfy@NiT2qwgb7gY@Sz2R@TaMFS4pwyekIr5jYapGqfP8AlE6daSrTrGJJmZ@nVQsbCDBqaNeZNffk95IKWaYrTIRVv6ULiZJ1fpdXIjhY50JQt1g4DcE5O6DIKu@8s6RS4a1X23GSonAltlSS7D31WTmv26Djsto41TMxfoK9oIBC4skj1NXdZfPoR@EJZjBvYebu4mZjdWoesdlBDjwhN1PjNo71J/Er1wNOfb6OgpEiSq3HmpHxDw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), 139 bytes

```pascal
uses strutils;var s:string;begin read(s);write(s=ReverseString(s))end.dne))s(gnirtSesreveR=s(etirw;)s(daer nigeb;gnirts:s rav;sliturts sesu
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY5BCsQgEAS/4lEPuw9YySeSF5jYkQGRMK3J890hx6IKuq/EI9XPeR1zDoKOXUeXyngndfwZSitxR5HmFCl7hviodHguK24osb2NiYCWv7khBPrSRPsGqjXrQo8u@kQTOUFdk4I9vo1tOE13ZJU@DJ29GHP6EPwf)

The program compares if the input is equal to its reverse using `ReverseString()` function from module `strutils`.

`end.` is the last part of the program. This program does not use comments because, in most cases, FPC does not care what is after `end.`, so the program without the dot is simply reversed and appended to the program itself.

Answer (score 0):

## T-SQL, 70 bytes

```sql
SELECT IIF(s=REVERSE(s),1,0)FROM t--t MORF)0,1,)s(ESREVER=s(FII TCELES
```

Didn't see a SQL version, so here's my try. Returns 1 for a palindrome, and 0 otherwise. `IIF` is supported by [SQL 2012 and later](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Input is via pre-existing table **t** with varchar field **s**, [per our IO rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341). The input table can include multiple rows.

The `--` in the middle is a comment character.

**Edit**: Here's a more clever version, using a strangely-named input table instead of an extended comment. Unfortunately slightly longer (**73 bytes**):

```sql
--"
SELECT IIF(s=REVERSE(s),1,0)FROM"MORF)0,1,)s(ESREVER=s(FII TCELES
"--
```

This requires an input table with a long strange name:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [MORF)0,1,)s(ESREVER=s(FII TCELES
] (s VARCHAR(999))
```

Note the return is included in the table name (*not* a recommended naming strategy for your databases, by the way).

Tables with otherwise invalid characters in their name need brackets or double-quotes around them, and the only way I could put the required quote at the beginning was to set it after a comment.

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 94

```
s=>Console.Write(s.SequenceEqual(s.Reverse()))//)))(esreveR.s(lauqEecneuqeS.s(etirW.elosnoC>=s
```

Improves slightly on the answer from [Anderson Pimentel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161051/82407)

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##XVDBasMwDD3HXyFychhNPyBLYJTeNgjNoYd1B@GqrZlrE8vJKKPf7qnksg2EpCc9oScZXpkQKU9s/RmGGye6Nuo3ql@tHxuljENm6NHd/DGGK6lvVXDCZA3MwR7hDa3XnKJMvn8AxjNXqhBO8WKSDf55aXXQQwuZ224TPAdH9T7aRJrrgcaJvKHtOKETvKOZIpOuqmq9FqeJo5R2NWuH07gl42kaaRBMycZ9TS6wD5uu5dzI2pOcheYCesYIDNYvmkBaD1XFv/3wBCWsOiirx3DRa16Sv7TyEA9@odyV2D1n@YH5DKL15MJXjmjIYJR4FI8efwA)

Answer (score 0):

## MUMPS, 36 bytes

```
r r r w r=$re(r) ; )r(er$=r w r r r
```

### Explanation

There are no reserved keywords in MUMPS; the compiler just uses context to decide if you you are referencing a routine, command, or variable.

`r` :  define routine "r"

`r r` :  read input and assign to variable "r"

`w r=$re(r)` : write 1 if "r" equals its reverse (`$re` is the shortened form of `$reverse`)

`; )r(er$=r w r r r` : lame comment to make palindromic

Ungolfed version:

```
palindromeRoutine
 read input
 write input=$reverse(input)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 11 bytes

```
.0(%=1=%(0.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPmvpGegoWpraKuqYaCn9B@J8/8/AA)

Outputs via error. Throws an `undefined method` error if the input is a palindrome and a `ZeroDivisionError` otherwise.