# Find out if this a valid Stack Cats program, in Stack Cats style!

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source

## Background

[Stack Cats](https://github.com/m-ender/stackcats) is a reversible esoteric language made by Martin Ender. Each command in Stack Cats is either the inverse of itself (represented as a symmetric character, such as `-_:T|`), or has its inverse command (represented as the mirror image, such as `()` `{}` `[]` `<>`). **Stack Cats has a strong syntactic requirement that the whole program should be the mirror image of itself.** Note that this means any valid Stack Cats program is a [natural mirror-image ambigram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambigram).

Here is the whole command set of Stack Cats:

- Self-symmetric: `!*+-:=ITX^_|`
- Symmetric pairs: `()` `{}` `[]` `<>` `\/`

Any other characters are invalid; any input having a character not in the character set above should output false.

The language has additional constraint that `()` and `{}` pairs must be always balanced, but for the sake of simplicity, you don't have to check for this condition.

The following are some examples of a **valid Stack Cats program** (again, note that you don't check for balanced parens):

```
{[+]==[+]}
[)>^<(]
({T)}|{(T})
<(*]{[:!-_:>}<[<)*(>]>{<:_-!:]}[*)>
```

These are not:

```
b<+>d
())(
({[<++<]})
```

## Challenge

Write a program or function that determines if the given string is a valid Stack Cats program. **Your code should also be a natural mirror-image ambigram**, which means:

- Your code should be a mirror image of itself.

  - Your code may have one or more newlines, as long as the whole code, displayed naturally, is a mirror image of itself.
  - You can omit or add trailing whitespaces on each line, since it doesn't change the display.
  - Tab characters are not allowed since they have some ambiguity on display.

**Note:** your code does **not** have to be a valid Stack Cats program; it may contain certain extra characters that are not allowed in Stack Cats. (See below for the complete list.)

For example, the following two programs are symmetric (and thus a **valid submission**), while the third is not:

```
({bTd})
[<q|p>]
```

```
({bTd})
  IXI
```

```
({bTd})
IXI
```

- Regarding "mirror symmetry", only Stack Cats-style vertical symmetry is considered (e.g. `({IH})` is not a valid submission, even though it has horizontal mirror symmetry).
- Your code can only contain these sets of characters, plus newline:

  - Self-symmetric: space (`0x20`) + `!"'*+-.8:=AHIMOTUVWXY^_ovwx|`
  - Symmetric pairs: `()` `/\` `<>` `[]` `bd` `pq` `{}`

The character set is chosen to be strictly symmetric or self-symmetric when displayed as code on SE.

## Input and Output

The input range is any **one-line string of printable ASCII characters**.

You can choose to take input as a string, a list of chars, or a list of ASCII values.

You can choose to output either:

- Any of the truthy/falsy values as defined by the language of your choice

  - The actual result values may differ between inputs (e.g. output 1 for a truthy input and 2 for another truthy one).
  - Swapping truthy and falsy values is not allowed.
- Any two constant values for true/false respectively

  - In this case, the result values should exactly be one of the two constant values.

You should specify your input method and output values in your submission.

## Winning Condition

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so lowest bytes in each language wins.

## Notes

- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden as usual.
- Of course you can solve this in Stack Cats, but the catch is that you can't use a flag that allows you to reduce your code size by half. And it's a seriously hard language to pick up. :P

Comment: Why sharp `#` disallowed?

Comment: @tsh It's slightly skewed in many fonts, including the code font on SE (at least it's what I see on Chrome).

Comment: @DLosc I tried to clarify some points around it. But if you think the description is still unclear, please feel free to edit.

Comment: [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/28190/8478) [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/142248/8478)

Answer (score 18):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>487</s> <s>467</s> <s>378</s> <s>298</s> <s>292</s> <s>280</s> <s>266</s> 264 bytes

*Saved 14 bytes thanks to @Bubbler*

```js
I=>(V=v=>!I[v]||((T=o=>[[]][+!!A[o]]||[(I[v]!=A[o]||A)[o^o<88/8]]+T(++o))(8-8)==I.pop())*V(++v))(V|(A='(){}[]<>\\/ !*+-:=ITX^_|'))//\\(('|_^XTI=:-+*! \//<>[]{}()'=A)|V)((v++)V*(()qoq.I==(8-8)((o++)T+[[8\88>o^o](A||[o]A=![v]I)]||[[o]A!!+][[]]<=o=T))||[v]I!<=v=V)<=I
```

Defines an anonymous function that takes an array of chars and returns the desired output. Output is truthy/falsy; usually `1`/`0`, but the empty string gives `true`.

### How?

The most obvious trick is to use `//\\` as a center point to comment out the mirrored version of the code. After that, it becomes a game of figuring out the shortest way to solve the problem using only the charset given.

The first issue we run into is the lack of keywords and built-ins. We miraculously still have `.pop()`, but everything else will have to be done via the allowed operators (which includes `a[b]` and `f(c)`), with recursion to emulate loops.

The second issue is the lack of logical operators. Neither `&` and `?` are allowed, which means the *only* decision-making operator we can use is `||`. Therefore, we have to carefully structure our logic to account for this.

The first thing I did was to define a function `T` that mirrors an individual character. The basic idea is to loop through each character in a string of mirror-able chars, testing each for equality with the given char. If it is equal, we return its mirror—the char at `index^1` for `(){}[]<>\/`, or the char itself for the rest.

The first problem I ran into here was getting either the mirrored char or a falsy value on each iteration. The solution I eventually came up with was `(x!=A[o]||A)[o^o<88/8]`, where `x` is the input character, `A` is the mirroring alphabet, and `o` is the current index. If `x` is not the same as `A[o]`, this gives `true`, and the index expression evaluates to `undefined`; otherwise, the `||A` is activated, and we end up getting `A[o^(o<11)]`.

The second problem is how to terminate the recursion. I found that the best way to do this is to simply concatenate the results of every iteration, returning the empty string when the end of `A` is reached. This presents us with two further problems: converting the `undefined`s to empty strings, and returning the empty string `||` something. These can be solved with array abuse: `[a]+""` gives the string representation of `a`, or the empty string if `a` is undefined. As a bonus, `[]` is truthy but stringifies to the empty string, so we can conveniently use this as a "truthy empty string".

Now we can use the `T` function to mirror any single character. We do this recursively, comparing the mirror of `I[v++]` to `I.pop()` until the end of the array of chars is reached. We can't use `&&` or `&` to check if all of the comparisons are truthy, but so use `*` instead. Multiplying all of these results together gives `1` if every character is the mirror of the one opposite, or `0` if any comparison fails.

And that is basically how this answer works. I probably didn't explain it very clearly, so please ask any questions you may have and point out any mistakes I have made.

Comment: `U=([A,...H])=>!(V=H.pop())||!(W=([x,...X]=(T="!*+-:=ITX^_|")+"(){}[]<>\\/",[o,...O]=T+")(}{][></\\")=>!x||((o!=A)+(x!=V))*(W(X,O)))()*U(H)//...` 280 bytes

Comment: @tsh *commas* are not allowed in the source code, as they are not symmetrical (in the SE code font) and have no mirror (in ASCII, anyway)

Comment: sorry, i missed that part.

Comment: @tsh I missed it too at first, and spent 20 minutes on a solution only to realize it couldn't be valid :P

Comment: Anyway, since you had already posted a JavaScript solution. We do not need another JSF\*k solution now... // If I were you,  I would fix this by just compile it to JSF\*k...

Comment: Starting with `o=>` should be fine, as I explicitly allowed "list of chars" as an input method.

Comment: @Bubbler Thanks, overlooked that possibility.

Answer (score 5):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>76</s> 70 bytes

```
:Wx^^MH_=_"{([</!*+-:=ITX^_|":W-!*pq*!-W:"|_^XTI=:-+*!\>])}"_=_HM^^xW:
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%3AWx%5E%5EMH_%3D_%22%7B%28%5B%3C%2F%21*%2B-%3A%3DITX%5E_%7C%22%3AW-%21*pq*%21-W%3A%22%7C_%5EXTI%3D%3A-%2B*%21%5C%3E%5D%29%7D%22_%3D_HM%5E%5ExW%3A&i=%7B%5B%2B%5D%3D%3D%5B%2B%5D%7D%0A%5B%29%3E%5E%3C%28%5D%0A%28%7BT%29%7D%7C%7B%28T%7D%29%0A%3C%28*%5D%7B%5B%3A%21-_%3A%3E%7D%3C%5B%3C%29*%28%3E%5D%3E%7B%3C%3A_-%21%3A%5D%7D%5B*%29%3E%0Ab%3C%2B%3Ed%0A%28%29%29%28%0A%28%7B%5B%3C%2B%2B%3C%5D%7D%29&a=1&m=2)

Stax is friend of Stack Cats and has internals to generate the later half of a Stack Cats program from the first half. If we don't care about the restriction on the source and don't need to check the charset, here is a 4-byte solution:

### 4 bytes

```
:R_=
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%3AR_%3D&i=%7B%5B%2B%5D%3D%3D%5B%2B%5D%7D%0A%5B%29%3E%5E%3C%28%5D%0A%28%7BT%29%7D%7C%7B%28T%7D%29%0A%3C%28*%5D%7B%5B%3A%21-_%3A%3E%7D%3C%5B%3C%29*%28%3E%5D%3E%7B%3C%3A_-%21%3A%5D%7D%5B*%29%3E%0Ab%3C%2B%3Ed%0A%28%29%29%28%0A%28%7B%5B%3C%2B%2B%3C%5D%7D%29&a=1&m=2)

### Explanation

```
:Wx^^MH_=_"{([</!*+-:=ITX^_|":W-!*pq...
:W                                         "Mirror" the string
                                           Equivalent to appending the reverse of the string to itself
                                           And map `{([</\>])}` to its mirror in the appended string
  x^^                                      2, but we can't just use `2` here ...
     MH                                    Partition the "mirror"ed string to two parts, take the later part.
       _=                                  The string is the same as the original one (*)
                                           `:Wx^^MH_=` is just `:R_=`, but we can't use `R` here ...
         _                                 Input string
          "{([</!*+-:=ITX^_|":W-           Remove valid characters from input
                                !          The final string is empty (**)
                                 *         (*) and (**)
                                  p        Pop and print result
                                   q       Peek stack and print
                                           Since the stack is now empty, this causes the program to terminate
                                    ...    Not executed
```

Comment: The existence of `R` and `W` is really interesting. Program termination by `pq` combination is also impressive to me.

Comment: Thank you. The instructions are actually two bytes: `:R` and `:W`. I feel that I can't help telling everyone there are internals in Stax that do this.