# To count the sum of all Unicode characters of a given input under an interesting constraint

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source, unicode

**Program:** To count the sum of all Unicode characters of a given input.

(No need to display the output. The final answer can be calculated in any base no need to convert back to hexadecimal.)

**Test case** : XyZ= 0058+0079+005A=012B

**Condition:** If the program is inputted, then its output must be an integral multiple of 1729 (hex 06C1). (Sum of all characters [(Unicode)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) in the code must be equal to an integral multiple of 1729.)

**Winning criterion:** code golf.

> [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20918/101710)

Comment: Can we output the result as a character with the code point of the sum value? E.g. `XyZ` → `ī`

Comment: There is no need to output, but doesn't mean we can't make any further innovative additions like this one, especially if saving code.

Comment: In my opinion this would be more interesting with the irreducible code constraint, which would prevent trivially appending a comment to meet the "1729 multiple" constraint, which most solutions are doing. As it stands the "1729 multiple" constraint is kind of pointless, as it is so trivial to meet in most languages.

Comment: I wanted to answer this in [Taxi](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/) but it can only handle ASCII up to 0x7F :(

Comment: Do `06C1` or `1729` have any special meaning?

Comment: It is a very interesting number; it is the smallest number expressible as the sum of two cubes in two different ways.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1729_(number)

Answer (score 23):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>20</s> 18 bytes

### Sheer luck!

```hs
sum.fmap(fromEnum)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzv7g0Vy8tN7FAI60oP9c1rzRX839uYmaegq1CQVFmXomCikKaghKmIqX//5LTchLTi//rJhcUAAA)

Comment: +1, You are tooooo lucky...........

Comment: @Wasif Check out the edit then ;)

Answer (score 6):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/nickbclifford/Ohm), 5 bytes

```
`Σʾ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr/P@Hc4lP7oBQA)

Comment: As `ʾ` isn't in [Ohm's code page](https://github.com/nickbclifford/Ohm/blob/master/code_page.md), you can't claim this as 3 bytes encoded in that code page, as is usually standard for Ohm programs. Instead, this should be run as a UTF-8 file, and be counted as 5 bytes

Comment: @ChartZBelatedly fixed

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 10 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319) ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

Anonymous tacit prefix function

```apl
+/⎕UCS ⍝õÿ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X1v/Ud/UUOdghUe9cw9vPbz/f9qjtgmPevsedTU/6l3zqHfLofXGj9omAhUFBzkDyRAPz@D/aQrqEZVR6lxAGl2/OpcGNlHNw9sNzY0sAQ)

`+` plus `/` reduction over `⎕UCS` Universal Character Set code points.

`⍝` is the comment symbol and the last two characters are fluff to reach 11×1729.

Comment: Ok, that is clever, I hadn't considered using comments.  :)  I'm still a little confused on when you have to use brackets/parentheses (and when/if they count towards your score), and the byte count difference between Dyalog Unicode and Classic.

Comment: Here's my attempt +⌿⍉⎕UCS⊢

Comment: @1_am_Jack That's amazing, however as-is, it isn't a proper solution. A slight reformulation fixes it: `+⌿⍉⊢⎕UCS` and you should post that!

Comment: I'd be happy to explain about byte counts, encodings, and parentheses, but I don't have time right now. Stop by in https://apl.chat one day, and I'll explain.

Comment: Thanks @Adám I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: I don't know APL, but maybe remove the space may save a byte? For example, `+/⎕UCS⍝⍝|`

Comment: @tsh Sure, that'd work.

Answer (score 6):

## Excel, <s>47</s> 43 bytes

<sup>*Saved 4 bytes thanks to Axuary*</sup>

```
=+sum(unicode(mid(F1,sequence(len(F1)),1)))
```

After input, Excel will autoformat it to look like this:

```
=+SUM(UNICODE(MID(F1,SEQUENCE(LEN(F1)),1)))
```

Input is in the cell `F1` and the formula can be in any other cell. Sum of codepoints is 3,458.

Comment: 43 bytes: `=+sum(unicode(mid(F1,sequence(len(F1)),1)))`

Comment: @Axuary It never even occurred to me to use anything but `A1` for input, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 8 bytes

```apl
+⌿⍉⊢⎕UCS

+⌿ ⍝ Column first summation
  ⍉ ⍝ Transpose (no-op)
   ⊢ ⍝ Identity function (no-op)
    ⎕UCS ⍝ Universal Character Set index values
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wTtRz37H/V2Pupa9KhvaqhzMFBUQT2iMkqdy9DcyFKhRgHIRVejDgA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 26 bytes

*Replace `?` with the byte `\x06` below:*

```sh
for	0	(${(s??)1})((B+=#0))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY6xCsJAEETLkPuKgZxkFxEuFhGRNPb2orEQ8TBNItkT1JBvj3sWgsXCsDO8mbfcJv9oL6HpWsFiJ/AbeOLJd33qUrIDSZJwMTLRdl5ljnky6iFcJYAMgP3rYBhDlPe@aQMs0VlhlXJsjDFz/B2zojypwWxGI5XNFVMHV4dvSf10Zby/qtz8iMoSxgzFarmGjvgA)

Zsh is super lenient about the characters used in parameter `${(flags)}`. The `(s)` flag expects a character, then the string to split on, then that character again. And it turns out control characters work perfectly well. (Although TIO wouldn't let me paste in `\x06`, so you get `\x07` in the TIO link, sorry).

I was fortunate that my first program was right around 2000 points, only a couple hundred bytes away from 1 x 1729. Minimizing parameter name codepoints, replacing spaces with tabs, and finally the control characters in flags got me all the way down.

Here's a more standard program:

```sh
for char (${(s[])1})      # split $1 (first parameter)
    ((result += #char))   # math function returns last math result
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 27 bytes

```python
lambda x:sum(map(ord,x))#Ԏ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCqrg0VyM3sUAjvyhFp0JTU/lK3/@Cosy8Eo00DSU8ipQ0Nf8DAA)

Program inputted unicode sum is `3458` which is `1729*2`, and integral multiple of `0x6C1` or `1729`

Trivial trick, base program unicode (`lambda x:sum(map(ord,x))#`) unicode sum is 2164, then `3458-2164` is 1294 and adding `chr(1294)` = `Ԏ` at the end results `3458`!

Comment: Since the challenge says "No need to display the output" I guess you could drop the lambda and use ```input()``` [24 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/5fUJSZV6Lxv7g0VyM3sUAjvyhFJzOvoLREQ1NTU/nGjv@aOKUA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Nice idea of adding extra compensate at the end

Comment: [`lambda ٱ:sum(map(ord,ٱ))`](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fnJ@SqmCroKSk9D8nMTcpJVHh5kar4tJcjdzEAo38ohSdmxs1Nf8DpfWKS4oyCzQ0udKAylPLEnM0QFo1uQqKMvNKNNIgPDSugr6CobmRpeZ/AA) is 26 bytes

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, <s>46</s> 42 bytes

```js
o=>[...o].map(z=>w+=z.codePointAt(),w=0)|w
```

Definitely not the best language for tasks involving character codes.

*-4 bytes thanks to Arnauld*

Comment: Oops, it's 3454 not 3458, editing

Comment: +1! You can save two bytes dropping the `0` from `charCodeAt`, using single char var names and using `.0` (or `0.`) for the initial `reduce` value too! [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/c1i5aT0@vPFavKDWlNDlVQ6NSp0rT1q5Su0ovOSOxyBmozrFEQ1NHz0DzvzVXcn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmra6uiaaEERQ0/o/AA "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Arnauld sorry I wasn't here earlier, I will edit your suggestions into the answer soon enough. I think I should learn how the assignment thing works like the way you did it

Answer (score 3):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 39 bytes

```
func[s][n: 0 foreach c s[n: n + c]n];ƈ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhIdy5Vm9T@tNC85ujg2Os9KwUAhLb8oNTE5QyFZoRgkkKegrZAcmxdrfazjf0FRZl6JQpqCEpEalLggOgzNjSwVtBSM/gMA)

2 x 1729

Answer (score 3):

## Java, 27 bytes

```
s->s.codePoints().sum()//ը
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYyxCsIwFEX3fsWjUzI0/QC10MVJQaibOMTUltQ0Cb6XQpH@jz/k98SIzk6XC@ecQU6yGNpbVEYiwv6RgQ8XoxUgSUozOd3CKLUF1tBd2/50rnmiYEimCKSN6IJVpJ0VR7dztt/@7vrLV9DBJmJRoVCuvR6ctoSMCwwj42X5esZVqjUz0nUULpDwySJjWSek92au8RNl@Z9CznlqLNkS3w)

## Java, 20 bytes

```
ù->ù.chars().sum()
```

This method does not work for all Unicode characters.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYyxDoIwFEV3vuKFqR14P6CSsDjphJtxqEW0WNqGvpIQw4cx82G1Rkenm5ucczoxiqJrnlFq4T0cXxm4cNVKgidBaUarGuiFMsBqGpS5ny8VTxR0ycRASmMbjCRlDZ7swZr7/ne3X76EFnZxXYpyXVA@xOAZRx96xuMmZerJ061HGwhdwkkb1qJwTk@V/9RY/k/NOU/ynM3xDQ)

Comment: That's impressively concise for Java.

Comment: @EricDuminil Unless otherwise specified, we are allowed to write a method/function instead of the whole program. See [Default for Code Golf: Input/Output methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).

Answer (score 3):

## [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org/), 16 bytes

Defines a function called `ǰ`. This sums to 1729.

```
ǰ=sum<..map$ord
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85Pzs8rLfn///gG2@LSXBs9vdzEApX8opT/BUWZeSUaxzdoKKFLKWlq/gcA)

`<..` is usually equivalent to `..` (function composition), but has a slightly lower precedence, which allows `map$ord` to be evaluated as partial function application without any parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 11 bytes

```
'ЌU¬mc r+ 
'Ќ        // Throwaway one-letter constant to pad the code to desired length.
  U¬      // Split the input to letters,
    mc    // map to char codes
       r+ // and reduce with summation.
```

[Try it here.](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=J1x1MDQwY1WsbWMgcis=&input=IidcdTA0MGNVrG1jIHIrIg==)

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 30 bytes

```powershell
"$args"|% T*y|%{$x+=+$_};$x#հ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0klsSi9WKlGVSFEq7JGtVqlQttWWyW@1lqlQvnqhv///6vjV6EOAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly) `u`, 4 bytes

```
؟OS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///GfP/g/xAKAA)

### How It Works

First, the `u` flag tells the interpreter to interpret this encoding as Unicode, rather the Jelly code page, otherwise the `؟` breaks the interpreter: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19B6cZ8/2AlBTuFtMycVL2s1JycSi4wqZBWiiQGVQeTwpT5/x8A)

When the program is actually run, `؟` is an unrecognised symbol, so breaks the parsing, forcing the parser to discard all characters up to the `؟` and begin parsing a new chain with `OS`

`OS` is fairly trivial as Jelly programs go: `O`rdinals then `S`um

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

Sums to `5*1729 = 8645`.

```
ÇO,₃
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cLu/zqOmZjgDAA)

`Ç` converts the input string to a list of unicode codepoints, `O` sums the list and `,` prints the result. `₃` pushes 95 to the stack, which is not printed implicitly since there was explicit output before.

[This program](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L4jbYfbXQ4v4jo1iUvBX@lwOxhrcykYmhtZqhoEctVyHV7@qGmNFxBXH555aPf//wA) was used to find a pair of characters (`,₃`) which are in the codepage and make the program sum to a multiple of 1729.

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, 13 bytes

```
[ Σ dup .o ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQnVqUl5qjkJtYkqFXmpeZnJ@SqlBQlFpSUllQlJlXolCcWliampecWqxgzVWtoBRRGaWkoBStcG6xQkppgYJevkKskkLtfxSB/7mJQMZ/AA)

### Explanation:

It's a function that takes a sequence as input, prints its sum in octal, and returns the decimal sum as output.

- `[ ... ]` A quotation. An anonymous function that lives on the data stack until called or used by a combinator.
- `Σ` take the sum of a sequence (a string is a sequence of unicode code points)
- `dup` duplicate object on top of the data stack
- `.o` print as octal

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 27 bytes

```r
sum(utf8ToInt(scan(,"ְ")))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7g0V6O0JM0iJN8zr0SjODkxT0NH6doGJU1NTbxyAA)

The second parameter of `scan` needs to be a string, but can be any string. In code golf, we usually use the empty string, but here using the single character string made of Hebrew Point Sheva (U+05B0) `"ְ"` makes the sum 3458=1729*2.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 11 bytes

```
﹪…%d⸿²ΣＥＳ℅ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3P6U0J1/DuTI5J9U5I79AQ0k1JaZISUfBSFNHIbg0V8M3sUDDM6@gtCS4BKghXQMo7F@UkpmXmKORqQkE1v//v9@56lHDMtWURzv2H9p0bvH7PUvf79n8qKX13M7/umU5AA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
        Ｓ   Input string
       Ｅ    Map over characters
          ι Current character
         ℅  Ordinal value
      Σ     Take the sum
﹪           Perform string formatting
  %d⸿       Literal string `%d\r`
 …   ²      Take first two characters
            Implicitly print
```

Slightly less satisfying 9 byte version:

```
→⭆¹ΣＥＳ℅λ↖
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMqKDM9o0RHIbgEyE33TSzQMARySnM1QEzPvILSEoiMhqaOgn9RSmZeYo5GjiYIWHP55pelaliFFvikppVoWv///6ht0qO1bYd2nlv8fs/S93s2P2ppPbf7Udu0/7plOQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
→
```

Print the next value left-to-right (i.e. default direction).

```
⭆¹
```

Cast the expression to string.

```
ΣＥＳ℅λ
```

Sum the codepoints of the input string.

```
↖
```

Move the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 18 bytes

```ruby
->ab{ab.bytes.sum}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZhvzX9cuMak6MUkvqbIktVivuDS39n@BQlq0UkRllFKsXkl@fLGGoZmmra26oVGSOhdYClOLUqytraG5keV/AA)

```ruby
x="->ab{ab.bytes.sum}";f=eval(x);f[x] #=> 1729
```